# Setting Django up to use MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, django, debian

I want to move away from PHP a little and learn Python. In order to do web development with Python I'll need a framework to help with templating and other things.

I have a non-production server that I use to test all of web development stuff on. It is a Debian 7.1 LAMP stack that runs MariaDB instead of the common MySQL-server package.

Yesterday I installed Django and created my first project called *firstweb*. I have not changed any settings yet.

Here is my first big piece of confusion. In the tutorial I followed the guy installed Django, started his first project, restarted Apache, and Django just worked from then on. He went to his browser and went to the Django default page with no problems.

Me however, I have to cd into my firstweb folder and run

```
python manage.py runserver myip:port
```

And it works. No problem. But I'm wondering if it is supposed to work like this, and if this will cause problems down the line?

My **second question** is that I want to set it up so it uses my MySQL database. I go into my settings.py under /firstweb/firstweb and I see ENGINE and NAME but I'm not sure what to put here.

And then in the USER, PASSWORD, and HOST areas is this my database and its credentials? If I am using *localhost* can I just put *localhost* in the HOST area?

Comment: Note: as od 01/2016 there is no MySQL driver for python 3.5.x. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34456770/python-connector-for-django-1-9-and-python-3-5
So use only up to Python 3.4. You can still use Django 1.9 (latest stable release as of 01/2016).

Comment: There is a workaround using PyMySQL as outlined [here](https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/02/04/how-to-use-pymysql-with-django/). You basically install and import `pymysql` and add `pymysql.version_info = (1, 4, 2, "final", 0)` and 
`pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()` right after you specify the `DATABASES` dictionary in `settings.py`. @TomasTintera

Answer (score 378, accepted):

[MySQL support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#mysql-notes) is simple to add. In your `DATABASES` dictionary, you will have an entry like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
        'USER': 'DB_USER',
        'PASSWORD': 'DB_PASSWORD',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

You also have the option of utilizing MySQL [option files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/databases/#connecting-to-the-database), as of Django 1.7. You can accomplish this by setting your `DATABASES` array like so:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'read_default_file': '/path/to/my.cnf',
        },
    }
}
```

You also need to create the `/path/to/my.cnf` file with similar settings from above

```
[client]
database = DB_NAME
host = localhost
user = DB_USER
password = DB_PASSWORD
default-character-set = utf8
```

With this new method of connecting in Django 1.7, it is important to know the order connections are established:

```
1. OPTIONS.
2. NAME, USER, PASSWORD, HOST, PORT
3. MySQL option files.
```

> In other words, if you set the name of the database in OPTIONS, this will take precedence over NAME, which would override anything in a MySQL option file.

---

If you are just testing your application on your local machine, you can use

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Adding the `ip:port` argument allows machines other than your own to access your development application. Once you are ready to deploy your application, I recommend taking a look at the chapter on [Deploying Django](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter12.html) on the [djangobook](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/index.html)

Mysql default character set is often not utf-8, therefore make sure to create your database using this sql:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydatabase CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin
```

If you are using [Oracle's MySQL connector](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-django-backend.html) your `ENGINE` line should look like this:

```
'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
```

---

Note that you will first need to install mysql on your OS.

```
brew install mysql (MacOS)
```

Also, the mysql client package has changed for python 3 (`MySQL-Client` works only for python 2)

```
pip3 install mysqlclient
```

Answer (score 30):

To the very first please run the below commands to install python dependencies otherwise python runserver command will throw error.

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
sudo pip install MySQL-python
```

Then configure the settings.py file as defined by #Andy and at the last execute :

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Have fun..!!

Answer (score 26):

If you are using python3.x then Run below command

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Then change setting.py like

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'DB',
     'USER': 'username',
    'PASSWORD': 'passwd',
  }
  }
```

Comment: I am using virtualenv with python 3.6. This saves my life. Thank you. Also, remember to create DB in mysql first

Answer (score 18):

As all said above, you can easily install xampp first from https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html
Then follow the instructions as:

1. Install and run xampp from http://www.unixmen.com/install-xampp-stack-ubuntu-14-04/, then start Apache Web Server and MySQL Database from the GUI.
2. You can configure your web server as you want but by default web server is at `http://localhost:80` and database at `port 3306`, and PhpMyadmin at `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`
3. From here you can see your databases and access them using very friendly GUI.
4. Create any database which you want to use on your Django Project.
5. Edit your `settings.py` file like:

   ```
   DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
       'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
       'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
       'PORT': '3306',
       'USER': 'root',
       'PASSWORD': '',
   }}
   ```
6. Install the following packages in the virtualenv (if you're using django on virtualenv, which is more preferred):

   sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev

   pip install MySQL-python
7. That's it!! you have configured Django with MySQL in a very easy way.
8. Now run your Django project:

   python manage.py migrate

   python manage.py runserver

Comment: Wii `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` install in `virtualenv` or globally?

Answer (score 7):

Actually, there are many issues with different environments, python versions, so on. You might also need to install python dev files, so to 'brute-force' the installation I would run all of these:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python3-dev
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
pip install MySQL-python
pip install pymysql
pip install mysqlclient
```

You should be good to go with the accepted answer. And can remove the unnecessary packages if that's important to you.

Answer (score 7):

**Run these commands**

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python3-dev
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
pip install MySQL-python 
pip install pymysql
pip install mysqlclient
```

**Then configure settings.py like**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'django_db',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '123456',
    }
}
```

**Enjoy mysql connection**

Answer (score 5):

1. Install `mysqlclient`

`sudo pip3 install mysqlclient`

if you get error:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   /tmp/pip-install-dbljg4tx/mysqlclient/

then:

```
 1. sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev python-mysqldb

 2. sudo pip3 install mysqlclient
```

---

2. Modify settings.py

   ```
   DATABASES = {
       'default': {
           'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
           'NAME': 'website',
           'USER': 'root',
           'PASSWORD': '',
           'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
           'PORT': '3306',
           'OPTION': {'init_command':"SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLE',"},
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Andy's answer helps but if you have concern on exposing your database password in your django setting, I suggest to follow django official configuration on mysql connection: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/databases/

Quoted here as:

```
# settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'read_default_file': '/path/to/my.cnf',
        },
    }
}


# my.cnf
[client]
database = NAME
user = USER
password = PASSWORD
default-character-set = utf8
```

To replace 'HOST': '127.0.0.1' in setting, simply add it in my.cnf:

```
# my.cnf
[client]
database = NAME
host = HOST NAME or IP
user = USER
password = PASSWORD
default-character-set = utf8
```

Another OPTION that is useful, is to set your storage engine for django, you might want it in your setting.py:

```
'OPTIONS': {
   'init_command': 'SET storage_engine=INNODB',
}
```

Answer (score 4):

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'django',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': '*****',
    'HOST': '***.***.***.***',
    'PORT': '3306',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'autocommit': True,
    },
}
```

}

then:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

if success will generate theses tables:

```
auth_group
auth_group_permissions
auth_permission
auth_user
auth_user_groups
auth_user_user_permissions
django_admin_log
django_content_type
django_migrations
django_session
```

and u will can use mysql.

this is a showcase example ,test on Django version 1.11.5:
[Django-pool-showcase](https://github.com/LuciferJack/Django-pool-showcase)

Answer (score 1):

Follow the given steps in order to setup it up to use MySQL database:

```
1) Install MySQL Database Connector :

    sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev

2) Install the mysqlclient library :

    pip install mysqlclient

3) Install MySQL server, with the following command :

    sudo apt-get install mysql-server

4) Create the Database :

    i) Verify that the MySQL service is running:

        systemctl status mysql.service

    ii) Log in with your MySQL credentials using the following command where -u is the flag for declaring your username and -p is the flag that tells MySQL that this user requires a password :  

        mysql -u db_user -p


    iii) CREATE DATABASE db_name;

    iv) Exit MySQL server, press CTRL + D.

5) Add the MySQL Database Connection to your Application:

    i) Navigate to the settings.py file and replace the current DATABASES lines with the following:

        # Database
        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

        DATABASES = {
            'default': {
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
                'OPTIONS': {
                    'read_default_file': '/etc/mysql/my.cnf',
                },
            }
        }
        ...

    ii) Next, let’s edit the config file so that it has your MySQL credentials. Use vi as sudo to edit the file and add the following information:

        sudo vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf

        database = db_name
        user = db_user
        password = db_password
        default-character-set = utf8

6) Once the file has been edited, we need to restart MySQL for the changes to take effect :

    systemctl daemon-reload

    systemctl restart mysql

7) Test MySQL Connection to Application:

    python manage.py runserver your-server-ip:8000
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a considerably old question but if anyone is working on any latest versions of python and django you can follow the following steps

```
Note - Versions
    Python version - 3.9.5
    Django version - 3.2.4
    MySQL server version - 5.7
```

After installing django, run the following command

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

In my IDE if I do `pip list` this is the list of Packages and Versions

```
Package     Version
----------- -------
asgiref     3.3.4
Django      3.2.4
mysqlclient 2.0.3
pip         21.1.2
pytz        2021.1
setuptools  57.0.0
sqlparse    0.4.1
```

Now, make sure you already have created the Database schema you are going to use.

In the `settings.py` file of your django project under DATABASES change

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

to

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
        'USER': 'DB_USER',
        'PASSWORD': 'DB_PASSWORD',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

You should be able to run both

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

and

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create a MySQL database first. Then go to `settings.py` file and edit the `'DATABASES'` dictionary with your MySQL credentials:

```
DATABASES = {
 'default': {
 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
 'NAME': 'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME',
 'USER': 'YOUR_MYSQL_USER',
 'PASSWORD': 'YOUR_MYSQL_PASS',
 'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP that your DB is hosted on
 'PORT': '3306',
 }
}
```

Here is a complete installation guide for setting up Django to use MySQL on a virtualenv:

http://codex.themedelta.com/how-to-install-django-with-mysql-in-a-virtualenv-on-linux/

Answer (score -1):

```
python3 -m pip install mysql-connector
pip install mysqlclient
```

These commands helpful to settingup the mysql db in django without errors

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it