# How to install Python MySQLdb module using pip?

Tags: python, mysql, pip

How can I install the [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) module for Python using pip?

Comment: If you're looking to use this with Python3 (e.g., with the newest version of Django) you'll need mysqlclient as MysqlDB doesn't support python3. See [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087598/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-configparser)

Comment: I'm using mysqlclient with Python 2.7 and MariaDB with no issues so far.

Answer (score 586, accepted):

It's easy to do, but hard to remember the correct spelling:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

If you need 1.2.x versions (legacy Python only), use `pip install MySQL-python`

Note: Some dependencies might have to be in place when running the above command. Some hints on how to install these on various platforms:

### Ubuntu 14, Ubuntu 16, Debian 8.6 (jessie)

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev libmysqlclient-dev
```

### Fedora 24:

```
sudo dnf install python python-devel mysql-devel redhat-rpm-config gcc
```

### Mac OS

```
brew install mysql-connector-c
```

if that fails, try

```
brew install mysql
```

Comment: You don't have to remember the whole name, you can use `pip search mysql` and find the one you need in the output.

Comment: @WKPlus: right... but I did `pip search mysqldb` and didn't find it.  Thus, I +1 this answer.

Comment: @WKPlus actually it's pretty much a real hassle to find out the right choice after a pip search of mysql

Comment: I have to google this every time, so damn infurating

Comment: On Ubuntu or any debian distribution, you could simply sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb . I tried using pip but it failed on my end.

Comment: @DavidOkwii When you're not inside a virtualenv, sudo is required. That might have been your problem.

Comment: I wish I could pin this answer to the front page of my SO home. Can that be a feature? I come to this answer at least once a week...

Comment: The intuitive package name would be: `pip install mysqldb`. That doesn't work.

Comment: Actually, under Mac OS, pip install fails with mysql-connector-c installed. However, it works with "brew install mysql" instead.

Comment: There is a fix for the current problem with Mac OS, brew and mysql-connector-c [here](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/issues/169#issuecomment-299778504)

Comment: This update of my mysql_config-file worked! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43740481/python-setup-py-egg-info-mysqlclient

Comment: On ubuntu, `build-essential` package is also a required dependency

Comment: Faced a lot of issues while installing the package for Python 3.6. Got a "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required" where I have Visual C++ 2015-2022 installed. Copied MySQldb folder from site-package from another system where the MYSQLDB is installed perfectly for python 3.6 and pasting in my current system

Answer (score 142):

Starting from a fresh Ubuntu 14.04.2 system, these two commands were needed:

```
 apt-get install python-dev libmysqlclient-dev
 pip install MySQL-python
```

Just doing the "pip install" by itself did not work.

From http://codeinthehole.com/writing/how-to-set-up-mysql-for-python-on-ubuntu/

Comment: this one worked, for some reason simple pip install doesn't work clean on ubuntu

Comment: In ubuntu 14.04, will get a error "raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,)", and the first cmd fixed the problem, thanks , save me some time

Comment: To fix `error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1` use `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Comment: I wonder why this is needed. One thing occurs to me. I tested this by installing only and not building. Did you build any of the things you installed rather than just install them?

Comment: This should be accepted answer of course for Ubuntu.

Comment: +1 This should be the answer for Ubuntu systems, it worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04.4. Solving my "ImportError: No module named MySQLdb" & ```Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MySQLdb (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for MySQLdb``` error msgs

Answer (score 34):

First

```
pip install pymysql
```

Then put the code below into `__init__.py` (`projectname/__init__.py`)

```python
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

My environment is (python3.5, django1.10) and this solution works for me!

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Woow, I have waisted over 5hrs trying to fix this without success. This is the only solution that worked on Ubuntu 16.04/python 3.5/Django 1.11. Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: this not work for me, My environment is python 3.7 and django 2.2. Please help me out.

Comment: This should be up there. I've been browsing for a solution for hours. I have a virtualenv with python 2.7 running django 1.6. I was not able to install MySQL-python nor mysqlclient. No matter whatever I tried I was getting a "fatal error: mysql.h". This one did the trick.

Answer (score 23):

I had problems installing the 64-bit version of MySQLdb on Windows via Pip (problem compiling sources)  [32bit version installed ok]. Managed to install the compiled MySQLdb from the .whl file available from [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

Alternative link:  https://archive.linux.duke.edu/pypi/simple/mysqlclient/

The .whl file can then be installed via pip as document in https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#installing-from-wheels

For example if you save in `C:/` the you can install via

`pip install c:/MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl`

Follow-up: if you have a 64bit version of Python installed, then you want to install the 64-bit AMD version of MySQLdb from the link above [i.e. even if you have a Intel processor]. If you instead try and install the 32-bit version, I think you get the unsupported wheel error in comments below.

Comment: Total fail. Unsupported wheel

Comment: I needed MySQL client. `pip install mysqlclient-1.3.7-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl` working great.

Comment: Went to [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python) to download `whl` file (I dl'd 64 bit to match my 64 bit Python install). Saved file into `c:/` directory and ran `pip install c:/MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl` It installed in seconds and was good to go. Too easy!

Comment: Worked for me as well, as pip install by name was failing.

Comment: the link to www.lfd.uci.edu is dead.. this appears to be a good alternative... https://archive.linux.duke.edu/pypi/simple/mysqlclient/

Answer (score 20):

well this worked for me:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

this is for python 3.x

Comment: This is the first solution that worked for me for python 3.5 / django 1.11

Comment: You could run into trouble with a mysql_config file missing. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475223/mysql-config-not-found-when-installing-mysqldb-python-interface

Answer (score 10):

Many of the given answers here are quite confusing so I will try to put it simply. It helped me to install this

```
pip install pymysql
```

and then use the following command in the python file

```
import pymysql as MySQLdb
```

This way you can use MySQLdb without any problems.

Comment: your answer does not make any sense since those are two diffrent models

Answer (score 9):

Go to pycharm then go to default setting --> pip (double click) -- pymsqldb..-- > install --after installing use in a program like this

```
import pymysql as MySQLdb

# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","root","test" )

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

# execute SQL query using execute() method.
cursor.execute("show tables")

# Fetch a single row using fetchone() method.
data = cursor.fetchall()
print (data)

# disconnect from server
db.close()
```

Comment: So for me MySQLdb was not working because virtual environment was referring to incorrect library. Using `import pymysql as MySQLdb` solved that.

Answer (score 8):

I tried all the option but was not able to get it working on Redhat platform.
I did the following to make it work:-

```
yum install MySQL-python -y
```

Once the package was installed was able to import module as follows in the interpreter:-

```
>>> import MySQLdb
>>>
```

Comment: The question was specificly mentioning `pip`. What distribution are you using? On Fedora 24, this works to install the module via pip:

`sudo dnf install python python-devel mysql-devel redhat-rpm-config gcc`, `sudo pip install MySQL-python`

Comment: I understand the question is via pip but I personally wasn't able to solve it by using pip. Hence i just shared my workaround which fixed the issue for me. I am using centos 6.8. pip list does not show anything related to mysql and when i do "pip install MySQL-python" it threw an error.

Now interestingly I figured out that once we install through yum i:e "yum install MySQL-python"  I am able to import MySQLdb.
Also once done with yum installation I was able to install via pip without any errors.

Answer (score 4):

If you are unable to install *mysqlclient* you can also install *pymysql*:

`pip install pymysql`

This works same as *MySqldb*. After that use pymysql all over instead of MySQLdb

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you are use Raspberry Pi [Raspbian OS]

There are need to be install pip command at first

```
apt-get install python-pip
```

So that just install Sequently

```
apt-get install python-dev libmysqlclient-dev

apt-get install python-pip

pip install MySQL-python
```

Comment: Raspberry is not mentioned in the question

Answer (score 3):

[image]

You can go to this [website](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient) to download the package.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem too.Follow these steps if you are on Windows.
Go to:
1.My Computer
2.System Properties
3.Advance System Settings
4. Under the "Advanced" tab click the button that says "Environment Variables"
5. Then under System Variables you have to add / change the following variables: PYTHONPATH and Path. Here is a paste of what my variables look like:
python path:

```
C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages;C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk;C:\Python27\Scripts
```

path:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.3.5\;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages;C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk;C:\Python27\Scripts
```

See this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440230/install-mysql-python-windows)  for reference

Answer (score 2):

`pip install mysql-connector-python`
as noted in the documentation:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation-binary.html

Answer (score 2):

If you have Windows installed on your system then type the following command on cmd :

```
pip install mysql-connector
```

if the above command does not work try using:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

Now,if the above commands do not get the work done, try using:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python-rf
```

That's it you are good to go now.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is great, but there may be some problems when we using pip to install MySQL-python in **Windows**

for example,It needs some files that are associated with **Visual Stdio** .One solution is  installing VS2008 or 2010……Obviously,it cost too much.

Another way is the answer of  @bob90937 . I am here to do something to add.

with http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs, u can download many  Windows binaries of many scientific open-source extension packages for the official CPython distribution of the Python programming language.

Back to topic,we can choose the **MySQL-python(py2)** or **Mysqlclient(py3)**   and use *pip install*   to install. it gives us Great convenience!

Answer (score 1):

For Python3 I needed to do this:

```
python3 -m pip install MySQL
```

Answer (score 1):

If pip3 isn't working, you can try:

```
sudo apt install python3-mysqldb
```

Comment: Not very good answer. You assume Python version is 3 and OS is Debian/Ubuntu, but you don't know that. Please wait until the author adds more details.

Answer (score 1):

**on RHEL 7:**

`sudo yum install yum-utils mariadb-devel python-pip python-devel gcc`

`sudo /bin/pip2 install MySQL-python`

Answer (score 1):

actually, follow @Nick T's answer doesn't work for me, i try `apt-get install python-mysqldb` work for me

```
root@2fb0da64a933:/home/test_scrapy# apt-get install python-mysqldb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libmariadbclient18 mysql-common
Suggested packages:
  default-mysql-server | virtual-mysql-server python-egenix-mxdatetime python-mysqldb-dbg
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libmariadbclient18 mysql-common python-mysqldb
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 29 not upgraded.
Need to get 843 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4611 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 mysql-common all 5.8+1.0.2 [5608 B]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 libmariadbclient18 amd64 10.1.38-0+deb9u1 [785 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 python-mysqldb amd64 1.3.7-1.1 [52.1 kB]                    
Fetched 843 kB in 23s (35.8 kB/s)                                                                                 
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common.
(Reading database ... 13223 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-common_5.8+1.0.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (5.8+1.0.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmariadbclient18:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libmariadbclient18_10.1.38-0+deb9u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmariadbclient18:amd64 (10.1.38-0+deb9u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-mysqldb.
Preparing to unpack .../python-mysqldb_1.3.7-1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-mysqldb (1.3.7-1.1) ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.8+1.0.2) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Setting up libmariadbclient18:amd64 (10.1.38-0+deb9u1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u3) ...
Setting up python-mysqldb (1.3.7-1.1) ...
root@2fb0da64a933:/home/test_scrapy# python 
Python 2.7.13 (default, Nov 24 2017, 17:33:09) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import MySQLdb
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

***You can follow the readme of mysqlclient.***
For example on MAC OS: as per the [readme for mysqlclient](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient/blob/master/README.md#macos-homebrew),
you will need to install `pkg-config` and (`mysql` or `mysql-client`):

> ```
> # Assume you are activating Python 3 venv
> $ brew install mysql pkg-config
> $ pip install mysqlclient
> ```
>
> If you don't want to install MySQL server, you can use mysql-client instead:
>
> ```
> # Assume you are activating Python 3 venv
> $ brew install mysql-client pkg-config
> $ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql-client/lib/pkgconfig"
> $ pip install mysqlclient
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (for Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt install -y python3-dev libmysqlclient-dev pkg-config build-essential
```

then:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

It seems pkg-config and build-essential are needed for the install.

Answer (score -1):

My environment are:

- Windows 10 Pro,
- Python 3.7 (python-3.7.1-amd64.exe),
- MySQL 8.0 (mysql-installer-web-community-8.0.13.0.msi)

pip install mysqlclient-1.3.13-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

works for me.

```
import MySQLdb, sys


# --------------------------------------------------
# Connect to MySQL
# --------------------------------------------------
try:
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="user", passwd="pass", db="database", charset='cp1251')
except MySQLdb.Error as e:
    print ("Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1]))
    sys.exit()

# Creating cursor 
cursor = db.cursor()
```