# MySQL not establishing connection to database

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to connect to a remote MySQL database and I'm running into this error

```
  "Lost connection to MySQL server during query (%s)" % (e,))
peewee.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query ([Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host)')
```

Here's the code

```
from peewee import *

print "connecting"
db = MySQLDatabase("mydb", user="myuser", passwd="crypticpassword!", port=someport, host="someremotehost.com")
db.connect()
print "connected"
```

so I figured, sure, let's try connecting without using code. I tried using Heidi, connecting through Microsoft SQL Server, and no problems whatsoever. Any ideas where I should look into to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have mysql downloaded
[How to install Python MySQLdb module using pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865270/how-to-install-python-mysqldb-module-using-pip)
Also import mysql

```
import MySQLdb
```

Comment: It's not an import issue.