# Model field types for Django 1.8.2 models that will work with MySQL database tables

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, database

Let's say I have the following table showing how the columns would be declared for a MySQL table: (I can't think of a very realistic example, so here's something that's so silly. This table is created with the help of Excel)

[image]

I want to create a model in Django that is compatible with the MySQL table I'll have with the columns declared this way. However, from looking at the Django documentation, I can't find any model field types that in SQL are the same format as those in the picture except for the primary key field.

I did see before that by default, Django handles a database that uses the SQLite Engine, but I want to see if it's possible to handle a database of MySQL tables.

**Is there a way to create Django model field types, like MEDIUMINT, TINYTEXT, and SMALLINT, (in MySQL) that are compatible with tables created through MySQL?** It's simply a way for me to use the tables that I created myself, not the tables that Django generates automatically once all the models are defined.

Comment: Django is database agnostic. All its core fields are compatible with all databases. There is nothing MySQL specific in your example.

Comment: How would I be able to accomplish this? Like, how would I declare a CharField, let's say, that when I migrate the app, it creates a column that's of type TINYTEXT?

Comment: Why do you care? Why must the field be of that type? Why not just create a TextField?

Comment: That's because I don't want to change the declaration of the columns. And excuse me if I did not realize beforehand that I can create custom fields; on the other hand, will I be able to create fields that have the same data type as those MySQL columns? (Otherwise, I want to see if I could use Django-defined model fields that will be able to hold data on a MySQL table. And I want to use TINYTEXT instead of TEXT to save up space.)

Comment: I'm new to creating Django models that use MySQL tables I've already created beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

In Django you normally create the models and let the framework generate the tables for you. If you have a legacy database you can use `python manage.py inspectdb` to generate the models from the database (see the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/legacy-databases/)). But if it isn't a legacy database and you've created it just now, you are fighting against the framework and making your life more complicated.

Comment: Let me try this out for once.

Comment: Okay, it seems I wasn't able to try this out yet because what I'm missing is a Python module named 'mysqldb.' I think I'll try this out later; I did came across something where I could download it, only it's of file type .whl, which I'm not sure of what it is.

Comment: A simple way of installing it is using pip. See this question: [How to install Python MySQLdb module using pip?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865270/how-to-install-python-mysqldb-module-using-pip).

Comment: I did this differently, and after working on a few things, I finally got it! I'll have to explain later. I'm kind of busy right now with writing up the code for the models.