# ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I did a lot of research but couldn't find any solution for this 
I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
  import MySQLdb
ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

I installed this as well: and got this.

```
yesh@Yesh:~/DBMS$ sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-mysqldb is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Someone please help me with this. I guess it has something to do with environment variables. I don't know exactly what that is. Thanks in advance

Comment: apt-get installs software to the OS, but you need the module to be available to your python interpreter.  This is probably a duplicate of
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865270/how-to-install-python-mysqldb-module-using-pip

Answer (score 2):

First ensure you have a python mysql driver installed:

```
sudo pip install pymysql
```

Add this to your settings.py:

```
# For PyMySQL
try:
  import pymysql
  pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
except ImportError:
  pass
```

You can test that it works by trying this:

```
$ ipython
import MySQLdb  #Confirm you get an error

import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
import MySQLdb  #No error
```