# python + SQL db runserver ERROR

Tags: django

Django runserver is not work
python + SQL db. If I install sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb. Make migrate is okey, tables is create but runserver ERROR

```
Failed to get real commands on module "mysite": python process died    with code 1: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 25, in <module>
         import MySQLdb as Database
         ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
         During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
         Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "/home/ivan/pycharm-2016.3.2/helpers/pycharm/_jb_manage_tasks_provider.py", line 25, in      <module>
        django.setup()
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
        app_config.import_models(all_models)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 199, in import_models
        self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
        from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
        class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 119, in __new__
        new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865270/how-to-install-python-mysqldb-module-using-pip) for installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have PyMySQL module installed, if not use this.

```
pip install pymysql
```

In settings.py, add following code just below import os.

### Your current code

```
import os
```

### Your new code

```
import os
try:
    import pymysql
    pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Yes I add this code before DATABASES settings, it worked