# Can't install msqlclient for django/python3 [OSX 10.12.4]

Tags: python, mysql, django, macos

when I'm running `python3 manage.py runserver` I get this message:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'. 
Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?
```

and because I'm using mysql database on python, I tried to install mysqlclient with pip3 I get another error:

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.10.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/dd/vlr9cjt17_j4ccyzz89mld1w0000gn/T/pip-build-wt6g2_0e/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/private/var/folders/dd/vlr9cjt17_j4ccyzz89mld1w0000gn/T/pip-build-wt6g2_0e/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 54, in get_config
        libraries = [dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith('-l')]
      File "/private/var/folders/dd/vlr9cjt17_j4ccyzz89mld1w0000gn/T/pip-build-wt6g2_0e/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 54, in <listcomp>
        libraries = [dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith('-l')]
      File "/private/var/folders/dd/vlr9cjt17_j4ccyzz89mld1w0000gn/T/pip-build-wt6g2_0e/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 12, in dequote
        if s[0] in "\"'" and s[0] == s[-1]:
    IndexError: string index out of range  

       ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/dd/vlr9cjt17_j4ccyzz89mld1w0000gn/T/pip-build-wt6g2_0e/mysqlclient/
```

Also i read online that mysqlclient is not supported by python3 but i get a similar error when trying to instal MySQL-python:

```
 Collecting MySQL-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/dd/vlr9cjt17_j4ccyzz89mld1w0000gn/T/pip-build-jp09s51k/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        from setup_posix import get_config
      File "/private/var/folders/dd/vlr9cjt17_j4ccyzz89mld1w0000gn/T/pip-build-jp09s51k/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

     ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/dd/vlr9cjt17_j4ccyzz89mld1w0000gn/T/pip-build-jp09s51k/MySQL-python/
```

How can I fix this and install mysql client for python or is there other method so I could use MySQL db in python?

Edit: python3 does support mysqlclient but not MySQL-python.

Comment: You are missing the Python MySQL "driver". There is an answer on how to install it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25865271/190823

Comment: after running: 'brew install mysql-connector-c' i got msg that its already installed "Warning: mysql-connector-c-6.1.9 already installed" and running pip install MySQL-python throws same error.

Comment: *I read online that mysqlclient is not supported by python3 but I get the similar error when trying to install MySQL-python*. You have that the wrong way round. MySQL-python only supports Python 2. If you are using Python 3 you need mysqlclient.

Comment: Yeah, my bad on that one. Still getting same error on both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what I did, but I think the problem for me was that I had a bad `$PATH`. I was trying to do one of the steps I found on Google and after resetting the `bash_profile` and setting the Python path again, it was fixed for me.