# setup mysql with django on mac os

Tags: python, mysql, django, macos, virtualenvwrapper

I am trying to setup mysql server with my django application but I am having trouble installing it correctly.

I used `brew install mysql` to install mysql server.

Then I used `pip install mysqlclient` which gives this error:

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.10.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/r9/n0ld0jk57x590rzq5kv8x4wc0000gn/T/pip-build-ZZb7dn/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 54, in get_config
        libraries = [dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith('-l')]
      File "setup_posix.py", line 12, in dequote
        if s[0] in "\"'" and s[0] == s[-1]:
    IndexError: string index out of range
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/r9/n0ld0jk57x590rzq5kv8x4wc0000gn/T/pip-build-ZZb7dn/mysqlclient/
```

Also tried, `pip install MySQL-python` but it also gives the same error message.

Am i doing something wrong here? Please guide me in the right direction, I recently shifted from linux to mac os and I am a little confused how things work here.

Note: I am trying to do this in a `virtual environment`.

Comment: Try `pip search mysql | grep mysql` and search for your desired module to install within pip. Then `sudo pip install my_beloved_module`.

Comment: I don't think that's the full error. The actual cause of the error may have been right above the message you've given; do you know what it was?

Comment: @ChihebNexus It is showing a number of packages that I think might work. I am not sure which one should I choose. They are too many.

Comment: Did you try easy_install mysql-python ?

Comment: @Kaushal I did right now. It gives me an error saying "IndexError: string index out of range".

Comment: That's strange, it looks like that's an error in mysqlclient's installation code. It looks like this might be worth reporting to the developers if you're not the only one: someone else seems to have had the error too: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43629713/3150837

Comment: @kamayani did you get any solution??

Answer (score 4):

For python3 + django 1.11 + mysql on mac. This worked for me:

1. `brew install mysql-connector-c`
2. edit mysql_config (locate it: `which mysql_config`)

Change the following in mysql_config:

```
# Create options #
libs="-L$pkglibdir"
libs="$libs -l "
```

To:

```
# Create options #
libs="-L$pkglibdir"
libs="$libs -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto"
```

3. `brew info openssl`
4. and finally `pip3 install mysqlclient`

and done.

Comment: For pipenv + mysql5.7 + django2 + python3, it's also working. Many thanks.

Comment: With virtualenv + mysq8 + django2 + python3.7, it's not working on Mac