# Cannot Installing mysql-python cannot build or use wheel

Tags: python, mysql, anaconda, mysql-python, spyder

I am trying to install mysql-python, I have tried two methods in pip

1. `python -m pip install mysql-python`

   - This does not work saying "Failed Building Wheel for MySQL-Python"
2. Downloading the wheels MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win_amd64 and MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win32 and trying to install each of them separately with the command 
   `python -m pip install filename`

   - This does not work in each case saying it is "not supported on this platform'

Does any one know what is wrong and how I can install mysql-python?

***Update***

Since writing this I am still having trouble getting MySQLdb working but have tried a few more things.

1) I am using Python 3.5 mysql-python is for Python 2.x, I should have been trying to install mysqlclient. However I am now having similar issues as above installing mysqlclient both with wheels and with just pip.

```
> pip install mysqlclient




 Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.10.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\teddy\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-lhtha0\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\teddy\appdata\local\temp\pip-stnbio-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release
    C:\Users\teddy\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Dversion_info=(1,3,10,'final',0) -D__version__=1.3.10 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include" -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\PC /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
    _mysql.c
    _mysql.c(29) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'my_config.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\teddy\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\teddy\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-lhtha0\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\teddy\appdata\local\temp\pip-stnbio-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\teddy\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-lhtha0\mysqlclient\
```

2) I have tried installing MySQL connector C. This hasn't changed anything.

3) I have tried getting it working on Spyder the IDE that comes with Anaconda

So can anyone suggest anything else

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25865271/2148023

Comment: Thanks Carles, I am on windows and mostly use Python 3.5, although I also have 2.7 installed. I have also started using Spyder in the Annaconda package.

I have tried to copy and paste the command from your link to ensure its right and got the same results.I have read the link and have also tried downloading the wheel files and installing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did it. There were two things I changed to get it working:

1. My Pip was pointing to an older version of Python I had on my
   computer and for some reason Idle was picking it up but not Spyder.
2. I had to move one of the mysql connector files from:

`C:\Program Files\MySQL to C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL`

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered.