# Error while installing python-mysqldb (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: python

I'm trying to install `python-mysql` with following command in Ubuntu 16.04 for Python 3.

```
sudo apt-get install pyhton-mysqldb
```

However, it gives me an error saying `E: Unable to locate package pyhton-mysqldb`.

Comment: Read ***very*** carefully what you typed.

Comment: Previous solution [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865270/how-to-install-python-mysqldb-module-using-pip)

Comment: `pyhton-mysqldb` or `python-mysqldb`, is typo?