# I cannot find where to get MySQLdb

Tags: mysql, homebrew, mysql-python

I got MySQL through Homebrew and after searching around also (supposedly) download MySQLdb by running `brew install mysql-connector-c` but after restarting the terminal I am still getting a '`No Module named MySQLdb`' error. How do I either get this module or is there a better module to use?

Comment: `mysql-connector-c` is the C API. It doesn’t install any Python module; you have to install something else on top of it.

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865270/how-to-install-python-mysqldb-module-using-pip any help?