# Using Python execute my project codes, Report "No module named MySQLdb" error

Tags: python

My Running Environment:
Python 2.7.14
Pycharm 2017.2
MySQL 5.7.20

Compiler result:
[the Compiler error as the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hl7Oq.png)

Comment: try `pip install mysql-python`!

Comment: Please don't post links to code or messages or images of code or messages, instead, post the text here as part of your question so that we can see it without needing to go off-site. That simplifies the effort of the people who you're asking to help you, as well as helping people stay safe from the potential of misleading or spam links.

Comment: @DavyM explain in great detail, you should search your mistake and ask again on SO!

Comment: already used the command : pip install mysql-python But no useful.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454854/no-module-named-mysqldb

Comment: @Sarit Did you have checks duplicate db command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Python MySQLdb module using pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865270/how-to-install-python-mysqldb-module-using-pip)

Comment: @Gahan checked with pip list & pip uninstall command. I founded ImportError: No module named MySQLdb issue.