# Can't install MySQL for Python

Tags: python, mysql-python

I've tried installing mysql by doing

```
pip install mysql
```

but I get this every time:

```
    Command "c:\users\j\appdata\local\programs\python
    \python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, 
    tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\jmodiano\\AppData\\Local\\
    Temp\\pip-install-z5ktsicz\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr
    (tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace
    ('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))
    " install --record C:\Users\j\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-
    record-99629v1_\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-
    managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in 
    C:\Users\j\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z5ktsicz\mysqlclient\
```

I've tried installing in a different folder but it always gives the same error. Not sure what I'm doing wrong as it seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: AFAIK mysql client (binary/devel version in your case for Windows) should be installed before. Smth like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/25865271/2971192 but for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is no binary wheel for [`mysqlclient` 1.3.13](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/1.3.13/) *at all* in PyPI, hence you would require a compiler to install this. There is a wheel for 1.3.12, but not for Python 3.7 that you're using.

You can install a wheel for it from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ - one of `mysqlclient‑1.3.13‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl`
 or `mysqlclient‑1.3.13‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl` - whichever bitness is correct.