# Troubles with installing _mysql module on pip in azure

Tags: python, azure, pip, python-module, windows-server

I am hosting a PHP/MySQL web app on an Azure Windows server. One of the lines in the PHP executes a python script but the script uses the MySQLdb module which I believe is part of the _mysql module.

I have tried using the pip commands in just about every directory that I could think of. I've also upgraded pip as well

sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev libmysqlclient-dev

pip install _mysql
pip install MySQLdb

D:/home/python364x64/pip.bat install _mysql

Error messages range from "'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
 to:
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MySQLdb (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for MySQLdb

Answer (score 0):

On windows server, you cannot use sudo, please use 'python -m pip' instead.
For python 3.x, you should install mysqlclient, If you need 1.2.x versions (legacy Python only), use pip install MySQL-python. See [How to install Python MySQLdb module using pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865270/how-to-install-python-mysqldb-module-using-pip).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm trying this and I am only getting "ERROR: unknown command "MySQL-python"" back. I have tried changing it to 'python -m pip _mysql' or 'python -m pip MySQLdb' and im getting the same error

Comment: You should use "python -m pip install <module name>". Please have a try with "python -m pip install MySQLdb" or "python -m pip install mysqlclient".