# python - pip install mysqlclient on Arch Linux

Tags: python, mysql-python, archlinux

I need to use [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) in Python 3.7:

```
import MySQLdb
```

this should install through the command `pip install mysqlclient` which however gives me an error on Arch Linux. It seems [prerequisites](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/) are missing.
I see that on other distributions, like Ubuntu, these can be installed via the command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev
```

Solutions are [available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865270/how-to-install-python-mysqldb-module-using-pip) for other distro, but I could not find them for Arch Linux.

Comment: I recommend you do a search using: `pacman -Ss python mysql`, and there you will find the option you want. In general, if the package in pip is called foo in archlinux, the corresponding package is python-foo, in your case it would be: `sudo pacman -S python-mysqlclient`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the end the solution was to install gcc and mysql

```
pacman -S gcc

pacman -S mysql
```

and just later run

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Answer (score 3):

Does it work through pacman? `pacman -S python-mysqlclient`

Answer (score 2):

If you install 'python-mysqlclient' with pacman  then you can install it without any problem.

1. `pacman -S python-mysqlclient`
2. `pip install mysqlclient`