# Problem installing mysqlclient for Django project (macOS)

Tags: mysql, django

When connecting my Django project to a database hosted on a remote VM, when I run `python3 manage.py run server` I get the error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

when I try `python3 -m pip install mysqlclient` to resolve the dependency, I get the error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysqlclient (from versions: 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.3.8, 1.3.9, 1.3.10, 1.3.11rc1, 1.3.11, 1.3.12, 1.3.13, 1.3.14, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0rc2, 1.4.0rc3, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.2.post1, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mysqlclient
```

I'd like to understand what is causing these issues and how to resolve it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your Python version? Post the output of `python3 -V`.

Comment: I ran it, it returns Python 3.9.7

Comment: I got to work! I ran `brew install mysql`

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work! For anyone facing the same issues run `brew install mysql` then try `python3 manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, you might try installing the *mysql-connector-c* first. It seems heavy-handed to have to install MySQL to use a driver.

From:
[How to install Python MySQLdb module using pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865270/how-to-install-python-mysqldb-module-using-pip)

Mac OS
`brew install mysql-connector-c`

if that fails, try
`brew install mysql`