# mysql-python install error: Cannot open include file 'config-win.h'

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, failed-installation

I am trying to run `pip install mysql-python connector` but it keeps giving me an error "*Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h'*".

The installation works fine on my Mac and another Windows machine, but not this one. I have downloaded Visual Studio C++ and tried installing as both 32 bit and 64.

```
_mysql.c(42) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No s
uch file or directory

error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\VC\\BIN\\c
l.exe' failed with exit status 2

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command C:\Users\Admin1\Desktop\python\virtual\Scripts\python.exe -c "import set
uptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Admin1\\Desktop\\python\\virtual\\build\\
MySQL-python\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).r
ead().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\admin
1\appdata\local\temp\1\pip-6pmwrd-record\install-record.txt --single-version-ext
ernally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\Admin1\Desktop\python\virtu
al\include\site\python2.7 failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Admin1\Desktop\py
thon\virtual\build\MySQL-python
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\Admin1\pip\pip.log
```

Comment: Take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972259/mysql-python-install-problem-using-virtualenv-windows-pip

Comment: try to install it from an executable setup file. (it's force installation and sometimes ignores the error).

Answer (score 165, accepted):

for 64-bit windows

- **install using wheel**

  ```
  pip install wheel
  ```
- **download from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python**

  For python 3.x:

  ```
  pip install mysqlclient-1.3.8-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
  ```

  For python 2.7:

  ```
  pip install mysqlclient-1.3.8-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
  ```

Comment: This was successful for me with all versions.  Also make sure to download the .whl file to the same directory you execute the pip install call from.

Comment: pip install MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl did the job for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `pip install mysqlclient-1.3.7-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl` worked for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wow! Would give you 100 votes if that was possible. I had been struggling with this issue for 3 hours!

Comment: also thanks, this worked for me too. Next time, when `pip install <module>` fails with cryptic vcvars or cl.exe errors, i will first search for wheels and avoid downloading and installing gargantula microsoft compilers which wont work afterwards.

Comment: I am getting this error: MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform. Any help?

Comment: I tried the other one also: MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform. It did not work

Comment: use new wheel mysqlclient-1.3.8-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

Comment: @CodeFarmer how it connected ? I am getting an error `not a supported wheel on this platform`

Comment: @ojuskulkarni you may try install a wrong version of wheel, carefuly chose  the one suit your enviroment e.g python version,  32bit/64bit need same with your python bit version not system.

Comment: @Vivek you should download "mysqlclient", not "MySQL_python", links are just below.
And you have to pick the right version : cp34 is for Python 3.4, cp35 is for Python 3.5, etc. Try both x32 and x64 versions (I have Windows 64 bits but I can only install win32 version, weird)

Comment: @pokemon blue it gives me below error..

Requirement 'mysqlclient-1.3.8-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
mysqlclient-1.3.8-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: @DeepakChawla First download the file in a specific directory and run the above mentioned command i.e.
pip install mysqlclient-1.3.8-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
inside that directory.
For me mysqlclient-1.3.12-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl worked although I had 64bit windows version.

Comment: Further note that the module is named MySQLdb so use `import MySQLdb`.

Comment: I wish I could upvote 100 times. This is the first time i'm working with databases on python and was unable to install the package on windows 7... it was fairly easy on ubuntu... Windows sucks!

Comment: I am also getting the same error, wheel not supported. My OS is windows 10 x64. I don't know what file to install, the mentioned file don't exist in the link

Comment: what if my os is linux and where can i find the wheel file?

Comment: `AssertionError: mysqlclient==1.3.8 .dist-info directory not found`

Comment: mysqlclient-1.3.8 is no more available at this link, 1.3.13 is now the version which is not supported with my Windows10 64-bit

Comment: "MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform."

Comment: Using Python 2.7, I was getting error "...is not a supported wheel on this platform" when tring to install Mysqlclient version 1.4.2, but I was able to install MySQL-python version 1.2.5. Solved my issue.

Comment: Gohlke's wheel repository is going to [shut down soon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72581592/what-to-do-when-gohlkes-python-wheel-service-shuts-down). How can we solve those issues without it?

Answer (score 63):

This didn't work for me:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

so I found this after a while on Stack Overflow:

```
pip install --only-binary :all: mysqlclient
```

and it went all through, no need for MS Visual C++ 14 Build tools and stuff.

Note: for now this doesn't work with Python 3.7, I also had to downgrade to Python 3.6.5.

Comment: I have been having the same issue on Windows 10 - this worked for me, thank you very much +1

Comment: Only this worked for me (I am also using w10). Thank you.

Comment: awesome, it really worked for me after finding a solution for 3-4 days. I am also on 64-bit Windows 10

Comment: Thanks. This is the only one that helped

Comment: This was perfect. I had tried so many other alternatives but this was a charm. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 12):

well this worked for me:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

this is for python 3.x in window 7 i am not sure about other windows os versions

Comment: Further note that the module is named MySQLdb so use `import MySQLdb`.

Comment: This fails on 64 bit python on Windows 10, installed via anaconda. After installing visual studio tools it still failed and seems unable to find the headers for 64 bit connector.

Comment: Worked on Windows 10 also

Comment: Yes you need this for python3 mysql connector MySQLdb on windows

Answer (score 6):

I am using Windows 10 and overcame this issue by running the `pip install mysql-connector` command in Windows PowerShell rather than the Command Prompt.

Comment: yes true.. for windows we should use power shell.. thank you

Answer (score 6):

you can try to install another package:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

This package worked fine for me and I got no issues to install.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you want to install package `MySQL-python` on Windows, maybe try `pip install` command with `--global-option`. See the example command below:

```
pip install MySQL-python ^
 --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir ^
 --global-option=build_ext ^
 --global-option="-IC:\my\install\MySQL-x64\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" ^
 --global-option="-LC:\my\install\MySQL-x64\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\lib\opt" ^
 --verbose
```

For this example, I fully installed **64-bit** version of `MySQL Connector C` in customized location of `C:\my\install\MySQL-x64\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\`.

By the way, I noticed that `pip install MySQL-python` by default always looks into directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include`, even if you're using 64-bit and/or have installed the driver at a different location. I tested on Python-2.7, and I guess this is a bug of either Python or MySQL-python.

Hope the above might be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked when I selected the correct bit of my Python version, NOT the one of my computer version.

Mine is 32bit, and my computer is 64bit. That was the problem and the 32bit version of  fixed it.

to be exact, here is the one that worked for me: 
mysqlclient-1.3.13-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl

Answer (score 0):

For `mysql8` and `python 3.7` on windows, I find previous solutions seems not work for me.

Here is what worked for me:

```
pip install wheel

pip install mysqlclient-1.4.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

python -m pip install mysql-connector-python

python -m pip install SQLAlchemy
```

Reference:
https://mysql.wisborg.dk/2019/03/03/using-sqlalchemy-with-mysql-8/