# Windows Python2.7 mysqldb installation error

Tags: windows, python-2.7, installation, mysql-python

I'm trying to install mysqldb for Python.
I'm running "pip install mysql-python"
and I keep getting this error:

running build_ext
  building '_mysql' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-2.7
  creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'fi
nal',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\PC /Tc_mysql.c /Fobui
ld\temp.win32-2.7\Release_mysql.obj /Zl
  _mysql.c
  _mysql.c(42) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for mysql-python
Failed to build mysql-python
Installing collected packages: mysql-python
  Running setup.py install for mysql-python
    Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='c:\users\scott~1.sco\appdata\local\temp\pip-bu
ild-nja4gr\mysql-python\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install -
-record c:\users\scott~1.sco\appdata\local\temp\pip-5htk1y-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'
final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\PC /Tc_mysql.c /Fob
uild\temp.win32-2.7\Release_mysql.obj /Zl
    _mysql.c
    _mysql.c(42) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "c:\python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='c:\users\scott~1.sco\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-nja4gr\mysql-python
\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\scott~1
.sco\appdata\local\temp\pip-5htk1y-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\scott
~1.sco\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-nja4gr\mysql-python

Can anyone tell me whats the problem?

Comment: Similar - https://stackoverflow.com/q/26866147

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install mysql-python (newer versions) in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37092125/cant-install-mysql-python-newer-versions-in-windows)

Comment: @AlexR no, that would be a duplicate of mine lol

Answer (score 8):

Download the  pre-compiled whl  file for `mysql-python` from  from Christophe Gohlke’s Library of pre-compiled python packages for windows from the below location.

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python

Now got to directory where you downloaded that file and open command prompt there.

Now run below command `pip install xxx.whl`

Best Luck !!

Answer (score 7):

You can try...

```
   pip install mysqlclient==1.3.4
```

It worked for me.

If the above command doesn't work try this...

```
 pip install --only-binary :all: mysqlclient
```

both worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

I got a same error.

I solved it by install [mysql-connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=378015)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing Visual Studio C++ from your system or the correct environment for VS is not set properly based on the error in your question: "error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2"

Please check if you have C++ compiler installed at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe". If you do not have this installed it is available from Microsoft here: [python27 Compiler](http://aka.ms/vcpython27)

If you have VS installed try running the pip install from visual studio command prompt ,which generally would have all the environment created or try to run vcvarsall.bat from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\" folder

Answer (score 2):

You can get a pre-compiled version from [Christophe Gohlke’s Library of pre-compiled python packages for windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/). Specifically, you can find the [MySQL_python package here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python)

Other alternatives would be to use a python distribution that comes with many packages pre-compiled and available for easy installation. Two examples are:

- [Anaconda Python Distribution](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/)
- [Enthought Canopy Python Distribution](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/)

Answer (score 1):

Simply go to the site:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python

and download mysqlclient wheel file according to your python version and operating system bit specification, then install the downloaded file with typing

```
pip install downloaded_whl_file_name
```

Finally install mysqldb with command:

```
pip install flask-mysqldb
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to install mysql-connector with the same bitness as my python.
So **although** I run 64bit windows 10, I have 32bit python 2.7 installed so I had to install **32bit** mysql-connector from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/6.0.html#downloads)
 to overcome the error.

Answer (score 0):

The following action, mentioned above by [zio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/458663/zio), has solved my problem:

You can get a pre-compiled version from Christophe Gohlke’s Library of pre-compiled python packages for windows. Specifically, you can find the [MySQL_python package here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python).
After get the file, install it using pip install.