# Can't install mysql-python (newer versions) in Windows

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python, python-module

I have `mysql-python` v1.2.4 installed just fine on my machine (Windows 8). I am using Python 2.7. I always got this below error every time I try to upgrade to v1.2.5. (still happens as of v1.3.7)

> ```
> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\
> ```
>
> 9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'fi nal',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.
>   0.2\include" -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\PC /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.wi n32-2.7\Release_mysql.obj /Zl
>       _mysql.c
>       _mysql.c(42) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
>       error: command 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft \Visual
>   C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
>
> ```
> ----------------------------------------   Rolling back uninstall of mysql-python Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import
> ```
>
> setuptools, tokenize;**file**='c:\
>   \users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-utz7of\MySQL-python\setup.py';ex
>   ec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open',
>   open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n' ), **file**, 'exec'))"
>   install --record c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-osy
>   _cg-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" fai led with error code 1 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-utz7of\MySQL
>   -python\

I've tried (and none work):

1. Installing VS2010
2. Changing Python Path
3. Using Wheel module (I got `Failed building wheel for MySQL-python`)
4. Installing Python MySQL connector. For both Python and C.
5. Installing `mysqlclient`
6. Installing using Exe installer from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-python/1.2.5

Do I miss something? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why do I get a down vote. It is similar to some questions, but I've tried their solution and none work. Please explain the down vote reason if you want to act that way

Comment: What happened when you used the exe installer?

Comment: It got installed just fine, but then I still fail to install `mysql-python`

Comment: How do you know it failed? Did you try to import it and get an error?

Comment: I keep getting the error I've pasted in the question. Can't find config-win.h, etc.

Comment: I also can't import MySQLdb

Comment: this error still continues in v1.3.7 (latest as of today) and the solution worked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Python2.7 mysqldb installation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32215285/windows-python2-7-mysqldb-installation-error)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solved it myself.

I use the wheel installer from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python.

There are two wheel packages there. The `amd64` one refuses to install on my platform (Windows) but the other one works just fine. I mean the file with this name:

```
MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win32.whl
```

Then install it by running this below command in the same folder with the wheel package.

```
pip install MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win32.whl
```

*Python 3.7*

Use `mysqlclient‑1.3.13‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl`

Comment: As of 2018 (now version 1.3.7) this still appears to be the only way to get Python working with MySQL on Windows.

Comment: As of 8/2019 this is the only thing that worked for me. Like OP, the 64bit version should have worked for me but wouldn't. 32bit seems fine so far.

Comment: One can use some additional flags with PIP to ask for a version of the package where a binary is available e.g. `pip install --only-binary :all: mysqlclient`. This might not install the current version, but will attempt to install one with a precompiled binary available for your platform. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51811349/1880657)