# while installing mysqlclient in django i got Following Error

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-rest-framework

Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/fd/83329b9d3e14f7344d1cb31f128e6dbba70c5975c9e57896815dbb1988ad/mysqlclient-1.3.13.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient: started
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command C:\Users\jaswitha\PycharmProjects\FirstProj\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\jaswitha\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\mysqlclient\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\jaswitha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-5mltk4fj-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\jaswitha\PycharmProjects\FirstProj\venv\include\site\python3.6\mysqlclient:
    C:\Users\jaswitha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

```
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,3,13,'final',0) -D__version__=1.3.13 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include" -IC:\Users\jaswitha\PycharmProjects\FirstProj\venv\include -IC:\Users\jaswitha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\include -IC:\Users\jaswitha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\include /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
_mysql.c
_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

----------------------------------------
```

Command "C:\Users\jaswitha\PycharmProjects\FirstProj\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\jaswitha\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\mysqlclient\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\jaswitha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-5mltk4fj-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\jaswitha\PycharmProjects\FirstProj\venv\include\site\python3.6\mysqlclient" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\jaswitha\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\mysqlclient\
You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: There are no wheels for mysqlclient 1.3.13 (which was released this week). Use `pip install --only-binary :all: mysqlclient` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51087608/1554386) and pip should install mysqlclient 1.3.12 without any issues.

Comment: This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37092125/cant-install-mysql-python-newer-versions-in-windows