# How to install mysqlclient?

Tags: python

I try to install mysqlclient on Windows 10 with 
pip install mysqlclient

I have visual studio 2019 and python 3.7.4 also the build tools the last one and I update the pip

But I get this error:

```
ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\users\ponce\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ponce\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yg2gzqfi\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ponce\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-34g102m_\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\MySQLdb
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,4,2,'post',1) -D__version__=1.4.2.post1 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include\mariadb" -Ic:\users\ponce\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\ponce\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /TcMySQLdb/_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\MySQLdb/_mysql.obj /Zl /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    _mysql.c
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.21.27702\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'c:\users\ponce\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ponce\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yg2gzqfi\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ponce\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-34g102m_\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ponce\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yg2gzqfi\mysqlclient\
```

Comment: It appears that you did not install the [MySQL prerequisites](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/).

Comment: MAybe you have an issue like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51118963/issues-installing-mysqldb-with-python-3-6-5-cant-open-mysql-h-and-cant-op/51119092

Comment: Thanks the problem was that I installed a python 32 bits version... I changed to 64 and works!