# pip install mysqlclient returns "fatal error C1083: Cannot open file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pip

Here is this issue:
I attempt to install mysqlclient like so

```
C:\Users\amccommon349>pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/fd/83329b9d3e14f7344d1
cb31f128e6dbba70c5975c9e57896815dbb1988ad/mysqlclient-1.3.13.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\amccommon349\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\AMCCOM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qcgo48hf\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\AMCCOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-q4yoftj8\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

c:\users\amccommon349\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
warnings.warn(msg)
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c/nologo/Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,3,13,'final',0) -D__version__=1.3.13 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include" -Ic:\users\amccommon349\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\include -Ic:\users\amccommon349\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\um" "-IC:\ProgramFiles (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\cppwinrt" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl _mysql.c
_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.14.26428\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I made sure I had all of the files needed from visual studios build tools, I downloaded the mysql-python connector, and updated my pip and setup tools. I am a complete beginner to this and would appreciate any input as to how to go about fixing this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install mysql-python (newer versions) in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37092125/cant-install-mysql-python-newer-versions-in-windows)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can download unofficial windows binaries for your python version using https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient. Then install it using pip. This way you'll be able to avoid the hassle of dealing with visual studio build tools.

Just download the mysqlclient.whl file most applicable to you. I think in your case it'll be

> mysqlclient‑1.3.13‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl

and run

```
pip install "path to the downloaded .whl file"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @NipunSampath

Comment: I tried this solution but it didnt work. Do i need to restart computer?

Comment: @Labeo what happens when you try this? And no you don't need to restart in order to get this working

Comment: I am still facing the same issue

Comment: You can see the log here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55542089/unable-to-install-mysql-client-1-3-12-getting-fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-inc

Comment: After installing mysqlclient-1.4.2-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl  i am facing this log

Comment: are you using python 3.7 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: ... which btw doesn't work (python 3.7 on win7 x64): ERROR: mysqlclient-1.4.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: oh I see, it's because python by default installs the 32bit version of itself instead of the 64bit version and doesn't even say that on or near the download button.

Comment: this is good answer for windows based machine, if you are using VC9

Comment: can you please help me? How to decide which binary to download?
**python version: 3.8.3** ,  
**python is 32 bit**,     
**windows is 64 bit**

Comment: try mysqlclient‑1.4.6‑cp38‑cp38‑win32.whl

Comment: yes right i was used this one but just forget so that i am here but thanks for help

Comment: Make sure that you download the right wheel. So consider the following basic:

(1) use cp38 if you have python 3.8

(2) if your python shell is in 64 bit, use the wheel ending with 64 and vice versa
(3) Having Windows in 64bit does not mean your python is in 64 bit, which was my case

(4) By starting the Python interpreter in the terminal, you can see your Python bit. My case: Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:43:08) [MSC v.1926 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Comment: I encounter the same problem while installing mysqlclient from pip, there is no need to download .whl files manually you can specify the version of the package you require.Below is my solution:

    pip install mysqlclient==1.4.6

Thank You.

Comment: @larsk. The link is working for me.

Answer (score 33):

This error occurs when trying to install mysqlclient for python32 in 64 bit environments.
Uninstall python and re-install 64 bit version. Then pip install mysqlclient will run with no errors.

Comment: Not really, he has answered the question by explaining the error.

Comment: I am using 64 bit version of python 3.9.0. Still facing the same issue while installing mysql.

Answer (score 24):

Well probably,this is one of the stupidest errors i have ever witnessed.
I have Python 3.7.3 32bit along with latest pip3 and i was installing wheels to my Python....and i stumbled on this STUPID error....
Probably my situation is a bit different but you can resolve it just by looking carefully at the error.... at first it seems something is missing and you start blaming you, Windows ,32/64bit and the list goes on and on..
Take a step back...*just take a step back and just read the nasty red error message*....  **read it really well**.
In my case it was

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\myUserName\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\MASTER~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z7x81g2q\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MASTER~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z7x81g2q\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\MASTER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-z1mvci5v\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\MASTER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z7x81g2q\mysqlclient\
    Complete output (30 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\MySQLdb
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Dversion_info=(1,4,2,'post',1) -D__version__=1.4.2.post1 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include\mariadb" -Ic:\users\MyUserName\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\MyUserName\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /TcMySQLdb/_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\MySQLdb/_mysql.obj /Zl /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    _mysql.c
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.21.27702\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\MyUserName\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\MASTER~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z7x81g2q\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MASTER~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z7x81g2q\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\MASTER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-z1mvci5v\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Have you read it well ?...i assume that you have everything ... the Build tools, the MySQL Connector C 6.1...you even moved it to Program Files (x86)...so what it wrong...?? ...
Now take a closer look

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Dversion_info=(1,4,2,'post',1) -D__version__=1.4.2.post1 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include\mariadb" -
```

I am pretty sure you saw it...STILL NO ?.... let me bold it for you

```
"-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include\mariadb" -
```

**mariadb**
Well it can't be any stupidest than this ...the installer looks for mariadb **includes** and later **libs** 
Just go to the mariadb site and download the MariaDB C/C++ connector and install it...
Well its not over.. 
Goto to C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include
and create folder mariadb...and copy paste the contents from the mariaDb connector installation **include** folder
*again* don't go way...go to 
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib and do again the same drill for the **lib** folder
so you should have

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include\mariadb  

C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib\mariadb
```

Now hit the `pip3 install mysqlclient`
and enjoy installing without a nag...the end

```
Successfully installed mysqlclient-1.4.2.post1
```

Comment: All this does for me is create 64 unresolved link errors. Nice catch though. I think I'm just going to install the 32 bit version and be done with it

Comment: Oh jeez, after struggling with the installation of mysqlclient this finally helped me out.

Comment: Thanks John. It really helped me out.

Comment: Thank you John.  It's work by install MariaDB Connector/C 3.0.10 Stable.
                          
`Installing collected packages: mysqlclient                                     
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... done                                  
Successfully installed mysqlclient-2.0.1`

Answer (score 13):

This is what solved my issue

- Install MySQL Connector/C (Archived Versions) from [here](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-c/)

It is probably installed in the following location
`C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1`

---

- Copy the entire folder `MySQL Connector C 6.1` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1`

---

- Try executing the command `pip3 install mysqlclient`.

Successful? Good Job!

---

Unsuccessful?

---

- Install MariaDB connector from [here](https://downloads.mariadb.com/Connectors/c/connector-c-3.0.4/)

Probably installed in the location

```
C:\Program Files\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C 64-bit
```

---

- Copy the contents from

`C:\Program Files\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C 64-bit\include`

and Paste into a folder.
Name it as `mariadb` and paste it to the location

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include\`

---

- Copy the contents from

  `C:\Program Files\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C 64-bit\lib`

and Paste into a folder name it as `mariadb` and paste it to the location

```
`C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib`
```

---

- Try executing the command `pip3 install mysqlclient`.

This worked for me

Comment: It works for me. Windows 11, Python 3.10.6 [MSC v.1932 64 bit (AMD64)]. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue (exactly same error) and tried all the solutions mentioned above, and neither of them worked (at least for me), actually I was about to pull my hairs over this issue till I found the solution in a very weird, simple and stupid way!! .

I did the following steps so that the problem solved and life got sweet again.

First I installed **`MySQL Connector/C`** from [here](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-c/)

Second (after installation finished) I copied **`MySQL Connector C 6.1`** folder **from** **`Program files/MySQL` into `Program files (x86)/MySQL`**

note that you might have to create `MySQL` folder if it doesn't exist in `Program files (x86)` (it didn't exist for me)

As simple as that, it worked for me, it seems for some (or all) 64-bit windows, pip or more probably `mysqlclient` setup script only searches `Program files (x86)` folder for some MySQL files (such as 'mysql.h') and doesn't search `Program files` and since doesn't find anything in `Program files (x86)` raises the error very dumb!!! isn't it

Comment: yes i tries many of the solutions above, but nothing worked for me, so i tried what u said in the comment and it worked for me perfectly. Thank u.

Comment: @user1655410 happy coding :)

Answer (score 4):

I encounter the same problem while installing mysqlclient from pip, there is no need to download .whl files manually you can specify the version of the package you require.Below is my solution:

```
pip install mysqlclient==1.4.6
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem with the 64 bit version of python on Windows 10. The following repaired the problem for me.

1. Install the 32 bit version of python for windows (currently version 3.7.1)
2. Install visual studio build tools
   https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017
   for C++
3. Install the 32 bit mysql connector version 6.1.11 from https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-c/

After this I was able to install mysqlclient with `pip install mysqlclient`.

*Hopefully someone will come up with a better solution that doesn't require downgrading to 32 bit because this is not a good solution, it just works. I found a way to work around the mysql issue but ran into the problem again while trying to install channels. It seems python 64 bit is looking for 32 bit libraries instead of 64 bit libraries on windows. So far this solution has solved all of my python build problems on windows.*

Answer (score 3):

None of the solutions above worked for me. Apparently I had to downgrade my Python from `3.7.x` to `3.6.4` and that solved the problem for me. [Downloadlink](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.4/python-3.6.4.exe) for `python=3.6.4`.

I would recommend to create a new virtual environment for this and not to uninstall your main python. Find extensive documentation on how to create a `venv` [here](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/).

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve it, I've gone to [this page](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient)

[image]

and downloaded **mysqlclient‑1.4.6‑pp373‑pypy36_pp73‑win32.whl**.

Then, placed it in a particular folder, opened the terminal in it, activated the virtual environment *venv* and ran

```
pip install mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

sometimes the error is of interpreter too, it was in my case. I was using 3.8 python and had installed it in D:/, so that's and was not installed properly.

So I uninstalled it and installed it again correctly and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

My requirement was version 1.4.6 so this worked for me. Also shared here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74758867/9674385.

pip install mysqlclient==1.4.6

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error with **python 3.12** on **windows 10**

```
PS C:\Users\juanf> pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.2.0.tar.gz (89 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for mysqlclient (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [46 lines of output]
      # Options for building extention module:
        library_dirs: ['C:/mariadb-connector\\lib\\mariadb', 'C:/mariadb-connector\\lib']
        libraries: ['kernel32', 'advapi32', 'wsock32', 'shlwapi', 'Ws2_32', 'crypt32', 'secur32', 'bcrypt', 'mariadbclient']
        extra_link_args: ['/MANIFEST']
        include_dirs: ['C:/mariadb-connector\\include\\mariadb', 'C:/mariadb-connector\\include']
        extra_objects: []
        define_macros: [('version_info', (2, 2, 0, 'final', 0)), ('__version__', '2.2.0')]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
      copying src\MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
      copying src\MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
      copying src\MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
      copying src\MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
      copying src\MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
      copying src\MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
      copying src\MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb\constants
      copying src\MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb\constants
      copying src\MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb\constants
      copying src\MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb\constants
      copying src\MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb\constants
      copying src\MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb\constants
      copying src\MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb\constants
      running egg_info
      writing src\mysqlclient.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src\mysqlclient.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to src\mysqlclient.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src\mysqlclient.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'src\mysqlclient.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying src\MySQLdb\_mysql.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
      running build_ext
      building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\src
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\src\MySQLdb
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-Dversion_info=(2, 2, 0, 'final', 0)" -D__version__=2.2.0 -IC:/mariadb-connector\include\mariadb -IC:/mariadb-connector\include -IC:\Python312\include -IC:\Python312\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tcsrc/MySQLdb/_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\src/MySQLdb/_mysql.obj
      _mysql.c
      src/MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.37.32822\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mysqlclient, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.2.1 -> 23.3.1
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

After some time i found two possible solutions:

1. Download the .whl file from the official pypi page for mysqlclient (https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/#files) and install it using `pip install "your whl file location"`
2. Download the MariaDB conector for your OS from (https://mariadb.com/downloads/connectors/) and install it. I notice the mariadb connector was being searched in a different folder than the one its installed by default `library_dirs: ['C:/mariadb-connector\\lib\\mariadb', 'C:/mariadb-connector\\lib']`. So, move the install files from `C:\Program Files\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C`  to `C:\mariadb-connector\`. Make sure you also have Microsft Visual Studio C++ Build Tools installed (For this download Visual Studio Community). After that execute `pip install mysqlclient`

Second option was the one i used, but both should work.

Edit:

You need to reinstall maria DB connector (in the default folder) for the library to work properly.

Comment: I had this same issue. Doesn't seem that `pypi` has a wheel for `Python 3.12`, so I went with the second route (including moving the files from the install-dir used by the installer to `C:\mariadb-connector`), and that did also work for me.

Answer (score 1):

read the error, its looking for mariadb connectors in `-IC:/mariadb-connector\include\mariadb`. download mariadb-connector "C connector" from https://mariadb.com/downloads/connectors/connectors-data-access/c-connector/ and install. go to installation folder `C:\Program Files\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C 64-bit` and copy `MariaDB Connector C 64-bit` folder to the location its looking for in your case `-IC:/mariadb-connector\include\mariadb`. so you should past it in `C:/` and rename it to `mariadb-connector` so it can find it.

Answer (score 0):

Wasted a lot of time to solve this error i found the solution that worked for me at least.

**When i tried to install MYSQL Client**

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

**1st error**

> MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory

---

And also tried to install Django Channels

```
pip install -U channels
```

**2nd error**

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Download Build tools : 
[Microsoft Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017)

Stack overflow : 
[How to install/select required Build Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Installed build tools. (Happy Coding)

---

**@Ralph Ritoch** solution worked for me and as well others those getting Mysql Client error.

But i also installed Django Channels so i followed these steps mentioned below

**Follow these steps**

1. Windows 10 64 bit
2. [Python 64 bit 3.7.3](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.3/python-3.7.3-amd64.exe)
3. [mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-winx64](https://cdn.mysql.com/archives/mysql-connector-c/mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-winx64.msi)
4. [Build tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017)

I also installed  [Django Channels 2.2.0](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) and not getting any kind of error.

[image: Successfully installed mysqlclient]

---

(Note)

**MySQL connector already installed into x86 directory**

> Copy c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\ directory to c:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\

So i did not changed the directory of MySQL Connector. (You can also check this)

Maybe work for you!

[Other Stack solution to change dirctory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972259/cannot-open-include-file-config-win-h-no-such-file-or-directory-while-inst)

---

**Possible Reasons**

Why we getting errors.

1. Python 32/64 bit Version
2. MySQL Connector 32/64 bit version
3. Directory issue
4. Window 32/64 bit version
5. Build Tools not installed (If getting Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required)

---

Thanks to all who posted their solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying the same for a Django project.
I tried using:
`pip install mysql-python` 
which gave me the following error:
`'mysql.h': No such file or directory`.

 After fiddling with requirements.txt which gave me yet another error

```
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/e9/51b544da85a36a68debe7a7091f068d802fc515a3a202652828c73453cad/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB) 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info: 
    Traceback (most recent call last): 
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module> 
      File "/tmp/pip-install-43_6cfva/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module> 
        from setup_posix import get_config 
      File "/tmp/pip-install-43_6cfva/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module> 
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser 
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
```

**Finally using this worked for me**:
`pip install mysql-connector`
`import mysql.connector`

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to comment on John's answer but my comment was too long so I had to make another answer. Sorry for that.

John, this helped me a lot, thanks. Not properly reading the logs is a bad habit for many people, myself included.

But instead of downloading the mariadb connector (or searching the net for a prebuilt wheel), I managed to do it with oracle's mysql connector. And I prefer to do symbolic links instead of copying files. Here's what I did using windows 10 x64, python 3.8 x64 and oracle's mysql connector x64:

```
# run this on an elevated command prompt if your user does not have permission to make symbolic links
# download and install https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-c/
mklink /d "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include\mariadb" "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include\mysql"
mklink /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL" "C:\Program Files\MySQL"
mklink /d "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib\mariadb" "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib\vs14"
mklink "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib\vs14\mariadbclient.lib" "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib\vs14\mysqlclient.lib"
SET INCLUDE=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include;%INCLUDE%
python3 -m pip install mysqlclient
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers, but it was not sufficient to solve my problem. However it put me on the right path :). 
To solve the error of the missing sys/types.h I had to copy this types.h file from "c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\sys\" to "c:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include\mariadb\sys\". Then I could finally install mysqlclient.

Answer (score 0):

for me, `pip install mysqlclient` was throwing error...

```
MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
```

```
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.20.27508\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

It seems mysqlclient is 64 bit. 
So I Forced both Python and pip to execute from the 64 bit directory.

Explicitly...

don't `run python -m venv myvemv and pip install -r requirements.txt`,

run the following...

```
C:\Users\mr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python -m venv [path to your virtual env goes here]
```

and

```
C:\Users\mr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to install **mysqlclient** into your system, I was not able to install it directly through command prompt it showed:

**Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process**

tried couple of other alternatives and got a solution:

- Click on start
- Search for python and click on open file location
  [click on open file location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnR3i.png)
- 3.Click on python(version e.g=2.7,3.8,3.9...etc)
  [right-click and open file location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rfkv3.png)
- 4.Click on scripts
- 5.Got to path on the top of the file explorer and type cmd
- 6. After command prompt opens type *pip install mysqlclient*
- 7.Installation starts and now you have *mysqlclient* in your system

Answer (score 0):

We can do so many things but if we miss to do python 64 bit in the 64 bit environment, the setup will not be completed.

So, we must confirm python 64 bit if our windows is 64 bit.

To see that you are in 64 bit or 32 bit, please run python command in the command prompt and see the result as like below:

[To check 32 or 64 bit of python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4tFI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share how I resolve it. I downgraded it to Python version 3.10 rather than using the new version 3.12. I tried all the solutions above but it did not fix the issue. So I tried to copy all my settings on my laptop and replicate it on my desktop and that solved my issue. Maybe in the future, they will fix it on the 3.12. But for now, it works fine.

By the way, the first error I got was Microsoft Visual 14 or higher after I fixed that issue it was a quick fix. That error came out
`fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h'` When I install all the requirments.

I tried downloading the .whl file but still does not work. Maybe this would also help other people who still have this issue. By the way, almost all servers where you host your Python/Django app have lower Python Versions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fairly simple way to solve this: install the latest version with:

pip install mysqlclient

Using version 1.4.6 resulted in failure after failure.  However, remove the version requirement and 2.1.1 installed without error.

Joe White

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer won't work for everybody.
Inspect the error carefully. Sometimes the compiler tries to include the directory `C:/mariadb-connector/include/mariadb`.

The error message in my case had this : `-IC:/mariadb-connector\include\mariadb`
Here's what I did:

1. Installed mariadb c connector
2. made a folder names mariadb-connector at the root of the drive C
3. pasted the contents of `C:\Program Files\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C 64-bit` in the **mariadb-connector** that I created.

And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

i just downgraded my pyhton version to 3.8 and it worked perfectly

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pip install --only-binary :all: mysqlclient
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding some explanation: what does `--only-binary :all:` do? Why does it fix the problem in the question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand no one looked at the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/), just install [MariaDB Connector](https://mariadb.com/downloads/#connectors) and set the environment variable `MYSQLCLIENT_CONNECTOR` to the root path of the mariadb connector (not mariadb). This was the only thing, that worked for my windows 11 pc

Answer (score -3):

In Command Line, Just type:

```
python --
```

instead of:

```
python --version
```

(This should show more details about the version including whether it is 32 or 64 bit)