# Failing to install mysqlclient in python virtualenv

Tags: python, mysql, pip

I am trying to create a website using Django and would like to use mySQL.
Thus, with the virtualenv activated, I'm using the following command :

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

This input gives the following error :

```
_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
```

The thing is installing it on my local python version worked like a charm ,I only face this error inside virtualenv.

I'm using python 3.7, pip and setuptools are up to date. The mysqlclient version installed locally is 1.3.13.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install mysqlclient returns "fatal error C1083: Cannot open file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51294268/pip-install-mysqlclient-returns-fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-file-mysql-h)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Cannot+open+include+file%3A+%27mysql.h%27%3A+No+such+file+or+directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try these things for windows 64-bit:

- **install using wheel**

  ```
  pip install wheel
  ```
- **download from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient**

  For python 3.x:

  ```
  pip install mysqlclient‑1.3.13‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
  ```

  For python 2.7:

  ```
  pip install mysqlclient‑1.3.13‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl
  ```

*If 64 bits versions are not working you can alternatively use the 32 bits versions :*

For python 3.x:

```
pip install mysqlclient‑1.3.13‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl
```

For python 2.7:

```
pip install mysqlclient‑1.3.13‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl
```

Comment: I'm getting the error "mysqlclient-1.3.13-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform." with this version. Using the 32 bits version worked out. Thanks.

Comment: Great answer. Seems like the only viable way to install mysqlclient is by first downloading it and installing it offline with the specific mysqlclient for your machine architecture and the python version installed on your platform.

Comment: This answer saved my butt - just mke sure you download the correct WHL (Wheel) file for your current Python version and 32/64 type.