# Unable to install pattern

Tags: python, design-patterns, text-analysis

I am unable to install pattern library using

```
pip install pattern
```

I am getting the following error regarding `mysqlclient`. Initially I was getting error on **Visual Studio** which I resolved following [the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

```
Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: python-docx, mysqlclient, beautifulsoup4, pattern
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\ashis.mohanty\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ASHIS~1.MOH\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e2m7rr0s\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ASHIS~1.MOH\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-7_2in4ff\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    c:\users\ashis.mohanty\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,3,13,'final',0) -D__version__=1.3.13 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include" -Ic:\users\ashis.mohanty\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include -Ic:\users\ashis.mohanty\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\cppwinrt" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
    _mysql.c
    _mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.15.26726\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2


 Command
 "c:\users\ashis.mohanty\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe
 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ASHIS~1.MOH\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e2m7rr0s\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
 '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install
 --record C:\Users\ASHIS~1.MOH\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-7_2in4ff\install-record.txt
 --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in
 C:\Users\ASHIS~1.MOH\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e2m7rr0s\mysqlclient\
```

Comment: This problem got resolved by following the link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51294268/pip-install-mysqlclient-returns-fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-file-mysql-h

Answer (score -1):

There my be some problem(or configurations needed) in Microsoft Visual C++....Try to Install Visual C++ with [Microsoft Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017).

Comment: This problem got resolved by following the link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51294268/pip-install-mysqlclient-returns-fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-file-mysql-h