# MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqlclient

I am trying to install mysqlclient in django virtualenv. But I get this error

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/f1/3bb6f64ca7a429729413e6556b7ba5976df06019a5245a43d36032f1061e/mysqlclient-1.4.2.post1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\adity\desktop\dev\blog\env\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\adity\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wxr9hw0f\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\adity\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-zjrz983m --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  running build_ext
  building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\MySQLdb
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,4,2,'post',1) -D__version__=1.4.2.post1 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include\mariadb" -Ic:\users\adity\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\adity\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /TcMySQLdb/_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\MySQLdb/_mysql.obj /Zl /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
  _mysql.c
  MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\adity\desktop\dev\blog\env\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\adity\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wxr9hw0f\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\adity\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-wtvbzmsb\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\users\adity\desktop\dev\blog\env\include\site\python3.7\mysqlclient:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\MySQLdb
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,4,2,'post',1) -D__version__=1.4.2.post1 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include\mariadb" -Ic:\users\adity\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\adity\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /TcMySQLdb/_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\MySQLdb/_mysql.obj /Zl /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    _mysql.c
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\adity\desktop\dev\blog\env\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\adity\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wxr9hw0f\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\adity\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-wtvbzmsb\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\users\adity\desktop\dev\blog\env\include\site\python3.7\mysqlclient" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\adity\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wxr9hw0f\mysqlclient\
```

I did found some of the solutions online on stackoverflow, they say mysqlclient does not support python 3.7 I need to install wheel from [this site](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient)

and i did try to install whl file. But the plb is i am unable to install inside virtualenv when i try to install this inside virtual env i get error something like this

> mysqlclient-1.4.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

How can i fix this problem?
i need to deploy my app on sql database on server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory" while installing mysql-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972259/cannot-open-include-file-config-win-h-no-such-file-or-directory-while-inst)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51294268/pip-install-mysqlclient-returns-fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-file-mysql-h) *(if not a duplicated)*

"Σωτήρης Τσακιρίδης" says:

> This error occurs when trying to install mysqlclient for python32 in 64 bit environments. Uninstall python and re-install 64 bit version. Then pip install mysqlclient will run with no errors.

If you use `pyenv` for Python management run the command in your project folder, for example:

```
pyenv local 3.6.8-amd64
```