# Unable to install mysql client 1.3.12 getting fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory

Tags: python, mysql, pip, mysql-python

I am trying to install  mysqlclient==1.3.12 from python 3.7.3 using pip install command and I am facing below error:

```
 _mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.20.27508\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

And below is the log:

```
 Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\rohit\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Rohit\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5ngodhpx\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-927n4lus --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7
  copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  running build_ext
  building '_mysql' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,3,12,'final',0) -D__version__=1.3.12 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include" -Ic:\users\rohit\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\rohit\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
  _mysql.c
  _mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.20.27508\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Found existing installation: mysqlclient 1.4.2
    Uninstalling mysqlclient-1.4.2:
      Successfully uninstalled mysqlclient-1.4.2
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\rohit\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Rohit\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5ngodhpx\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-wi5jfwfg\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,3,12,'final',0) -D__version__=1.3.12 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include" -Ic:\users\rohit\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\rohit\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
    _mysql.c
    _mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.20.27508\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of mysqlclient
  Moving to c:\users\rohit\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysqlclient-1.4.2.dist-info\
   from c:\users\rohit\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\~ysqlclient-1.4.2.dist-info
  Moving to c:\users\rohit\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysqldb\
   from c:\users\rohit\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\~ysqldb
Command "c:\users\rohit\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Rohit\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5ngodhpx\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-wi5jfwfg\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5ngodhpx\mysqlclient\
```

I Tried the following solutions available in stack over flow

```
1) Uninstall and installed Python 3.7
2) Installed Visual studio build tools 2019
3) Copied the mysql connector.C 6.1 folder to C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL
4) Tried to download the whl files of mysql and install from command prompt. installed mysqlclient-1.4.2-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
```

I am working on Windows 10 64 bit and python 3.7.3

Any other solutions to fix this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install mysqlclient returns "fatal error C1083: Cannot open file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51294268/pip-install-mysqlclient-returns-fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-file-mysql-h)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Cannot+open+include+file%3A+%27mysql.h%27%3A+No+such+file+or+directory

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issues and the only thing that worked for me was the first line of code from this website [Unable to install mysql client 1.3.12 getting fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55542089/unable-to-install-mysql-client-1-3-12-getting-fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-inc). You have to be using the anaconda command prompt so download that if you haven't already. 
The code

conda install -c bioconda mysqlclient

is what I used and it worked well.

I hope this helps!