# Errors while installing Flask-MySQLdb using pip in virtual environment

Tags: python, mysql, flask, pip, mysql-python

In my virtual environment, i installed flask ( `pip install flask` ) and then Flask-MySQLdb ( `pip install Flask-MySQLdb` )

```
(venv) E:\Flask>pip install Flask-MySQLdb
```

I checked that Flask is properly installed:

```
(venv) E:\Flask>flask --version
Python 3.8.3
Flask 1.1.2
Werkzeug 1.0.1
```

---

But while installing `Flask-MySQLdb` I'm getting following error:

```
Collecting Flask-MySQLdb
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/e3/955c845efe1aacf30c8e2607470544ede36aa1044f6382c809f13e014104/Flask-MySQLdb-0.2.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Flask>=0.10 in e:\flask\venv\lib\site-packages (from Flask-MySQLdb) (1.1.2)
Collecting mysqlclient (from Flask-MySQLdb)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/e1/e5f2b231c05dc51d9d87fa5066f90d1405345c54b14b0b11a1c859020f21/mysqlclient-2.0.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in e:\flask\venv\lib\site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->Flask-MySQLdb) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10.1 in e:\flask\venv\lib\site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->Flask-MySQLdb) (2.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in e:\flask\venv\lib\site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->Flask-MySQLdb) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.15 in e:\flask\venv\lib\site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->Flask-MySQLdb) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in e:\flask\venv\lib\site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->Flask>=0.10->Flask-MySQLdb) (1.1.1)
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient, Flask-MySQLdb
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'e:\flask\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Nitish\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-l__3nshn\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Nitish\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-l__3nshn\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Nitish\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-6biidbgp\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'e:\flask\venv\include\site\python3.8\mysqlclient'
         cwd: C:\Users\Nitish\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-l__3nshn\mysqlclient\
    Complete output (23 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'e:\flask\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Nitish\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-l__3nshn\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Nitish\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-l__3nshn\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Nitish\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-6biidbgp\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'e:\flask\venv\include\site\python3.8\mysqlclient' Check the logs for full command output.
```

> My python version: **3.8.3**
> My pip version: **19.2.3**

---

Update:
I installed Microsoft Visual C++ tools. Now I'm getting these errors:

```
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'e:\flask\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Nitish\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kwo28o72\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Nitish\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kwo28o72\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Nitish\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-_plr9xlx\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'e:\flask\venv\include\site\python3.8\mysqlclient'
         cwd: C:\Users\Nitish\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kwo28o72\mysqlclient\
    Complete output (29 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\MySQLdb
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(2,0,1,'final',0) -D__version__=2.0.1 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include\mariadb" -Ie:\flask\venv\include -IC:\Python\Python383\include -IC:\Python\Python383\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\winrt" /TcMySQLdb/_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\MySQLdb/_mysql.obj /Zl /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    _mysql.c
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'e:\flask\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Nitish\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kwo28o72\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Nitish\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kwo28o72\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Nitish\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-_plr9xlx\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'e:\flask\venv\include\site\python3.8\mysqlclient' Check the logs for full command output.
```

---

## RESOLVED

1. initially the error was related to Microsoft Visual Build Tools:

```
     error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

So I installed Visual Build Tools

2. then I got error:

```
     MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
        error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

It happens to be that the error was due to 32 bit version python installed on 64 bit system as pointed out here(https://stackoverflow.com/a/53790200/13504510). The error was resolved by following the steps from this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51294860/13504510
for my case it got solved by installing this:

> **mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win32.whl**
> from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient)
> Try out which works for you. If the **whl** file is not supported on your system, then it should look like this:

```
pip install mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
ERROR: mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

otherwise it will get installed successfully!
After that again try `pip install Flask-MySQLdb` and it should do the job!