# i am trying to create a venv but get a weird error even though I have everything installed (in VS)

Tags: python, mysql, visual-studio, libmysqlclient

```
`2023-05-12 14:26:14.216 [info]  copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-38\MySQLdb\constants
      copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-38\MySQLdb\constants
      copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-38\MySQLdb\constants
      copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-38\MySQLdb\constants
      copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-38\MySQLdb\constants
      running build_ext
      building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-38
  
2023-05-12 14:26:14.217 [info]     creating build\temp.win32-cpython-38\Release
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-38\Release\MySQLdb
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(2,1,1,'final',0) -D__version__=2.1.1 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C\include\mariadb" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C\include" "-Ic:\Users\swagw\Documents\PROJECT FOR SOFTWARE ENGINEERING\.venv\include" -IC:\Users\swagw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include -IC:\Users\swagw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /TcMySQLdb/_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-cpython-38\Release\MySQLdb/_mysql.obj
      _mysql.c
      MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.35.32215\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
2023-05-12 14:26:14.217 [info] 
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

2023-05-12 14:26:14.218 [info]   ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient

2023-05-12 14:26:14.218 [info] Failed to build mysqlclient

2023-05-12 14:26:14.219 [info] ERROR: Could not build wheels for mysqlclient, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

2023-05-12 14:26:14.399 [info] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\swagw\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.8.0\pythonFiles\create_venv.py", line 77, in run_process

2023-05-12 14:26:14.399 [info]     subprocess.run(args, cwd=os.getcwd(), check=True)
  File "C:\Users\swagw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 512, in run

2023-05-12 14:26:14.399 [info]     raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError
2023-05-12 14:26:14.399 [info] : Command '['c:\\Users\\swagw\\Documents\\PROJECT FOR SOFTWARE ENGINEERING\\.venv\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-r', 'c:\\Users\\swagw\\Documents\\PROJECT FOR SOFTWARE ENGINEERING\\requirements.txt']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\swagw\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.8.0\pythonFiles\create_venv.py", line 232, in <module>

2023-05-12 14:26:14.399 [info]     main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "c:\Users\swagw\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.8.0\pythonFiles\create_venv.py", line 228, in main

2023-05-12 14:26:14.400 [info]     install_requirements(venv_path, args.requirements)
  File "c:\Users\swagw\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.8.0\pythonFiles\create_venv.py", line 97, in install_requirements

2023-05-12 14:26:14.400 [info]     run_process(
  File "c:\Users\swagw\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.8.0\pythonFiles\create_venv.py", line 79, in run_process
    raise VenvError(error_message)

2023-05-12 14:26:14.400 [info] __main__.VenvError: CREATE_VENV.PIP_FAILED_INSTALL_REQUIREMENTS

2023-05-12 14:26:14.407 [error] Error while running venv creation script:  CREATE_VENV.PIP_FAILED_INSTALL_REQUIREMENTS
2023-05-12 14:26:14.407 [error] CREATE_VENV.PIP_FAILED_INSTALL_REQUIREMENTS`
```

I tried most of the things on this thread and still got the error [pip install mysqlclient returns "fatal error C1083: Cannot open file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51294268/pip-install-mysqlclient-returns-fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-file-mysql-h)
any help would be appreciated

Comment: what did you do to get this error please ?

Comment: the other goes about pip install where micorsoft developer tools are used to compile the client, but you seem to have open something in vs 2022, what exactly was that.