# src/MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory

Tags: python, mysql, libmysqlclient

Getting this Error while trying to
pip install mysqlclient

I have the latest Version of Windows 11 22621.

Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
Building wheel for mysqlclient (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for mysqlclient (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [46 lines of output]
# Options for building extention module:
library_dirs: ['C:/mariadb-connector\lib\mariadb', 'C:/mariadb-connector\lib']
libraries: ['kernel32', 'advapi32', 'wsock32', 'shlwapi', 'Ws2_32', 'crypt32', 'secur32', 'bcrypt', 'mariadbclient']
extra_link_args: ['/MANIFEST']
include_dirs: ['C:/mariadb-connector\include\mariadb', 'C:/mariadb-connector\include']
extra_objects: []
define_macros: [('version_info', (2, 2, 0, 'final', 0)), ('**version**', '2.2.0')]
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
copying src\MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
copying src\MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
copying src\MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
copying src\MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
copying src\MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
copying src\MySQLdb_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
copying src\MySQLdb_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb\constants
copying src\MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb\constants
copying src\MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb\constants
copying src\MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb\constants
copying src\MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb\constants
copying src\MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb\constants
copying src\MySQLdb\constants_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb\constants
running egg_info
writing src\mysqlclient.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to src\mysqlclient.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to src\mysqlclient.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'src\mysqlclient.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
adding license file 'LICENSE'
writing manifest file 'src\mysqlclient.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
copying src\MySQLdb_mysql.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\MySQLdb
running build_ext
building 'MySQLdb.*mysql' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\src
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\src\MySQLdb
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-Dversion_info=(2, 2, 0, 'final', 0)" -D__version*_=2.2.0 -IC:/mariadb-connector\include\mariadb -IC:/mariadb-connector\include -IC:\Users\Adnan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include -IC:\Users\Adnan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/MySQLdb/_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\src/MySQLdb/_mysql.obj
_mysql.c
src/MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mysqlclient, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I have tried answers from this. [pip install mysqlclient returns "fatal error C1083: Cannot open file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51294268/pip-install-mysqlclient-returns-fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-file-mysql-h)

Answer (score 0):

go back to python version 3.11 until the bug is fixed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved by downgrading to Python 3.8, the wheel for the mysqlclient is not updated by the developer on the GitHub so he promised to update it at end of Dec 2023.

reference: https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient/issues/672