# pip install mysql error

Tags: python, mysql, macos, pip

I am getting the below error when trying to `pip install mysql`:

> building '_mysql' extension
>           creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7
>           /usr/bin/clang -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12/include/mysql -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/_mysql.o
>           _mysql.c:44:10: fatal error: 'my_config.h' file not found
>           #include "my_config.h"
>                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           1 error generated.
>           error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

Any ideas?

Comment: Which OS are u on.?

Comment: High Sierra 10.13.4

Comment: You have `xcode` installed.? If not try `xcode-select --install` after that install `mysql`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install mysql-python (newer versions) in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37092125/cant-install-mysql-python-newer-versions-in-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't have my_config file. It is because you have not installed mysql on your computer. Try to install after setup mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
brew remove mysql
brew install mysql@5.7
brew link --force mysql@5.7
pip install mysql-python
```

Comment: Explain what is happening here in text, instead of just posting terminal commands