# pip and installing mysql-python

Tags: python

I'm trying to install MySQL-Python through pip with pip `install MySQL-Python`. But I'm getting a couple of error messages. Here's the console log:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install mysql-python
Collecting mysql-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Building wheels for collected packages: mysql-python
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for mysql-python ... error
  Complete output from command c:\anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Rasmus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-cfm09c14\\mysql-python\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\Rasmus\AppData\Local\Temp\tmps09l9dk_pip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
  copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
  running build_ext
  building '_mysql' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -Ic:\anaconda3\include -Ic:\anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\winrt" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
  _mysql.c
  _mysql.c(42): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for mysql-python
  Running setup.py clean for mysql-python
Failed to build mysql-python
Installing collected packages: mysql-python
  Running setup.py install for mysql-python ... error
    Complete output from command c:\anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Rasmus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-cfm09c14\\mysql-python\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Rasmus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-u6i7y7az-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -Ic:\anaconda3\include -Ic:\anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\winrt" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
    _mysql.c
    _mysql.c(42): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Rasmus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-cfm09c14\\mysql-python\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Rasmus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-u6i7y7az-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Rasmus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-cfm09c14\mysql-python\
```

I tried downloading the two whl files and install them 'manually' from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python but they give the error:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install C:\Users\Rasmus\Downloads\MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I used python 3.5, and windows 10.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866147/mysql-python-install-fatal-error try this.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your pip version is outdated.

1. So first do `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`
2. Then use your downloaded wheel, but do `python3 -m pip install [.whl_location]` if python3 is in your path, else navigate to python3 folder and do the same.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The upgrade tells me it's up to date. And typing -m pip install C:\Users\Rasmus\Downloads\MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl says that python3 is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: You got to navigate to python3 folder and type only `python` as that is the name of the .exe in your case