# MYSQLdb with Python 3.6

Tags: python, mysql, pycharm

I'm having a very hard time installing MYSQLdb under Python 3.6. I've been fighting with this for about a day now and was hoping someone had a fix. Note I am running Windows 10, MY SQL Workbench 6.3, PyCharm 2016.3.2, and Python 3.6 as already mentioned. To begin with, when trying to execute code in PyCharm which includes an import of MYSQLdb, I'd get an error saying no module found. So, I of course tried to pip install basically every binary possible. For most, I'd get the following:

```
C:\Users\[me]>pip install mysql-python
Collecting mysql-python
Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Building wheels for collected packages: mysql-python
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for mysql-python ... error
Complete output from command c:\python36\python.exe -u -c "import 
setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\[me]\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-90yksnqx\\mysql-python\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Local\Temp\tmprh_xynj1pip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -Ic:\python36\include -Ic:\python36\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
_mysql.c
_mysql.c(42): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Failed building wheel for mysql-python
Running setup.py clean for mysql-python
Failed to build mysql-python
Installing collected packages: mysql-python
Running setup.py install for mysql-python ... error
Complete output from command c:\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\[me]\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-90yksnqx\\mysql-python\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-h7ydssnj-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -Ic:\python36\include -Ic:\python36\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
_mysql.c
_mysql.c(42): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

So, I even then tried installing the unofficial binary for 3.6 available at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

This installed fine, but still no luck when executing in PyCharm.

Next, I went into preferences=>project interpreter in PyCharm and tried to install MYSQLdb directly from there. With that, I get this other error:

```
Collecting MySQLdb

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MySQLdb (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for MySQLdb
```

From my research this seems to happen a lot when using new releases of Python. Does anyone know of a workaround or when 3.6 will be supported?

Comment: please reference here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866147/mysql-python-install-fatal-error

Answer (score 1):

try to use sqlalchemy that is fully suported for many ODBC driver. Insted of using mysqldb, mysqlconnector is better in python3.x. I migrated a project from sqlite to mysql server and work fine in python3.6
sqlalchemy offer a solution for connecting with another ODBC.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue.

I followed the advice of another answer and got to SQLAlchemy using the pip below:

```
pip install SQLAlchemy
```

I have been unable to play with it yet, but it did install without error, so here is hoping!

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue before and I found out that when using python 3.6 you just need to install mysqlclient:
1 - create a folder and than a virtualenv (virtualenv myvenv --python python3)
2 - Install the django version you want (pip install django==1.9.3)
3- Install mysqlclient (pip install mysqlclient)
If you go inside myvenv folder/lib/python3.6/site-packages you will see that MySQLdb module will be there.