# I am attempting to install the MySQL library using pip but I am getting an odd error

Tags: python, mysql, pip

In CMD I am entering pip install MySQL-python. This is the output error:

```
    Collecting MySQL-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Installing collected packages: MySQL-python
  Running setup.py install for MySQL-python ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\paint\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\paint\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-r4io9vrf\\MySQL-python\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\paint\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ltci1jrf-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.6
    creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -Ic:\users\paint\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include -Ic:\users\paint\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
    _mysql.c
    _mysql.c(42): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\paint\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\paint\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-r4io9vrf\\MySQL-python\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\paint\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ltci1jrf-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\paint\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-r4io9vrf\MySQL-python\
```

I have done a lot of reading but I cannot find any logs like this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This question has already answered [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866147/mysql-python-install-error-cannot-open-include-file-config-win-h)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql-python install error: Cannot open include file 'config-win.h'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866147/mysql-python-install-error-cannot-open-include-file-config-win-h)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `python install wheel` first, then install MySQL package 
`pip install mysqlclient.whl`