# I am trying to install "pip install mysqlclient" and it fails everytime. Tried all other things but also didnt work. What should I do?

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x, pip

I am trying to `install pip install mysqlclient` and it fails everytime. I also tried `pip install --only-binary :all: mysqlclient` and also not worked. Then I also downloaded whl file and also did't work. I need help.
Using python 3.7.2 and pip 19.0.2 version.
Here's the whole error thats pop up:

````
Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\vertig~1.0\envs\mypro\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\VERTIG~1.0\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b81i8gmq\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\VERTIG~1.0\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-6s1gmot9\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\users\vertig~1.0\envs\mypro\include\site\python3.7\mysqlclient:
  running install
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  running build_ext
  building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

  ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\vertig~1.0\envs\mypro\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\VERTIG~1.0\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b81i8gmq\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\VERTIG~1.0\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-6s1gmot9\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\users\vertig~1.0\envs\mypro\include\site\python3.7\mysqlclient" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\VERTIG~1.0\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b81i8gmq\mysqlclient\```

So any ideas where the error is getting?
````

Comment: Since you are a new contributor, i'll suggest you to always post the error message with your question. Otherwise no one can actually help you. Better edit your question and add the error message you received. Also add pip and mysql version you are using.

Comment: Install 64 bit Python 3.7.x if you can. There is an official wheel for 64 bit Python 3.7 on Windows. If you use 32 bit Python, you’ll have to install from source (which can be tricky) or [install an unofffical wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51164104/113962).

Comment: @Alasdair I already installed 64 it python and also download 64-bit wheel file. And also tried this in cmd: `pip install mysqlclient-1.4.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64` and it shows this: `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysqlclient-1.4.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mysqlclient-1.4.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64`

Comment: @hackSlanger can I ask how to check my mysql version in cmd

Comment: If you want to install a downloaded wheel, then you need the full filename including `.whl`.

Comment: @Alasdair I also tried with .whl but didn't work that's why I used trying without extension

Comment: *didn't work* isn't enough information. We can't help if you don't show the exact command and the error.

Comment: @VinceD you can run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and then go and check the requirements.txt file with <PACKAGE_NAME>==<VERSION>, where PACKAGE_NAME is the mysql-client or any other package you are using and VERSION is the package's used version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft
>   Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

From the error message its pretty clear that the issue is with with C++ installation on your machine.

FYI: Many Python libs uses C++ under the hood so its mandatory to install the Microsoft visual c++(on windows) as mentioned in the error.
You can go ahead and install Microsoft Visual C++ from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145) or [here](https://www.scivision.co/python-windows-visual-c++-14-required/)

Or else if there is no particular use behind mysqlclient you can use this pure pyython MySQL client library named [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL) (you need not install visual c++ for using this lib).

Answer (score 3):

Check that you have MySQL installed on your system.

On Mac:

`brew install mysql`

Installing with APT (eg, Ubuntu):

`sudo apt install mysql-server`

Or install with the installer: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/.