# Why do I get an error when I run pip install MySQL-Python?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, mysql-python

I am desperately trying to set up django, but I continuously run into problems.

When I run "pip install MySQL-python", I run into a wall of text in red and errors that is shown below. My problem is I cannot install django.

This is my first post on stack overflow, so please be easy on me if I messed up any formatting etc. I am not experienced in coding and the fact that I cannot even get basic stuff like this to work is extremely discouraging.

```
    C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install MySQL-python
    Collecting MySQL-python
    Using cached 
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/e9/51b544da85a36a68debe7a7091f068d802fc515a3a202652828c73453cad/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Building wheels for collected packages: MySQL-python
  Building wheel for MySQL-python (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\chrispa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Chrispa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ts0ir3mr\\MySQL-python\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Chrispa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ts0ir3mr\\MySQL-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Chrispa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-4pjpg8hv' --python-tag cp37
       cwd: C:\Users\Chrispa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ts0ir3mr\MySQL-python\
  Complete output (29 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7
  copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  running build_ext
  building '_mysql' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.22.27905\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -Ic:\users\chrispa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\chrispa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.22.27905\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.22.27905\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.7.2\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
  _mysql.c
  _mysql.c(42): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.22.27905\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for MySQL-python
  Running setup.py clean for MySQL-python
Failed to build MySQL-python
Installing collected packages: MySQL-python
  Running setup.py install for MySQL-python ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\chrispa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Chrispa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ts0ir3mr\\MySQL-python\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Chrispa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ts0ir3mr\\MySQL-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Chrispa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-wedev03m\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\Chrispa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ts0ir3mr\MySQL-python\
    Complete output (29 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.22.27905\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -Ic:\users\chrispa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\chrispa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.22.27905\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.22.27905\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.7.2\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
    _mysql.c
    _mysql.c(42): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.22.27905\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\chrispa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Chrispa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ts0ir3mr\\MySQL-python\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Chrispa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ts0ir3mr\\MySQL-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Chrispa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-wedev03m\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: MySQL-Python only works with Python 2, use `mysqlclient` instead. If you are following a tutorial or book that recommended MySQL-Python then it’s out of date and you should be wary of using it. Unless you have a good reason to use 32-bit Python, I would reinstall 64-bit Python instead. The command `pip install mysqlclient` should work for Python 3.7 64-bit on Windows for the current release 1.4.4. For other releases/Python versions, you can [download an unofficial wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51164104/113962).

Comment: your problem is you cannot install Django or you cannot install MYSQL-Python in your Django project ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting Django up to use MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189813/setting-django-up-to-use-mysql)