# pip install mysqlclient on win64 not working giving error 'Cannot open file: 'mysql.h'

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to use mysql with python SQLAlchemy but while installing mysqlclient for python its giving error. kindly check details below:

- I'm running this on Windows 10 64 bit and Anaconda Python 3.7.4
- I have tried by installing another python version as well but no luck.
- Tried to install MYSQL connector c++ as well. but still not working.
- If I run code 'pip install mysqlclient'

mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Comment: Look at answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51146117/installing-mysqlclient-in-python-3-6-in-windows Try to use pure python MySQL connector PyMySQL for example: https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got an answer by looking at other options mentioned here.
Actually mistake was that,

- I have installed Python 3.7.4 with 32 bits on 64bits machine.
- Code was looking for below path but it was going to the wrong path in program files instead of program files(x86)

C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib

I have installed a new Python with 3.7 with 64 bits and also while installing MySQL connector I have changed the path of installation to the above-mentioned path and now it's working fine.

Thank you, everyone, for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

based on [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51294268/pip-install-mysqlclient-returns-fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-file-mysql-h), you can download unofficial windows binaries for your python version using [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient). for example, "mysqlclient‑1.3.13‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl".
Then install it using pip.

```
pip install "path to the downloaded .whl file"
```

**Note:**  In the name of the wheels, there are numbers that show this wheel is for which python version. for example if only you have python **version 3.6**, you can use "mysqlclient‑1.3.13‑**cp36‑cp36m**‑win_amd64.whl".
After all, if you still have error, **try 32bit version** of wheels.

Comment: I have tried that as well. but it says unsupported file

Comment: I have download 'mysqlclient‑1.4.6‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl' from link you shared. and run command 'pip install mysqlclient‑1.4.6‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl'

Comment: What is your python version?

Comment: The version that you download is for python 3.8, as mentioned in the name of the wheel (cp38‑cp38‑win) . if you have another version of python, download the related wheel.