# mysqlclient-1.3.12-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to connect `MySQL` with my `Django` project. My python version is `3.8.3`. So first I run `pip install mysqlclient`, and it says the following error:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": 
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```

Then I install Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools on my laptop from that link. But The error still arise.

Now I try with offline installer `pip install mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl` by download file from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient). Now it says the following error:

```
ERROR: mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Again I try to install `wheel` by running `pip install wheel`, and it says:

```
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in g:\python\lib\site-packages (0.36.2)
```

**N.B**: I also search it in StackOverflow, and try almost all method from this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51146117/installing-mysqlclient-in-python-3-6-in-windows). But nothing is working for this.

I just need to use `MySQL` with my `Django` project. **Please suggest how to fix it? or any kind of alternative to run `MySQL`?**