# Got errors when installing DREAM

Tags: python, simpy

I'm new to Manpy. I tried to follow the instructions in the documentation, and I got some errors when installing.

1. Download dream-master into a folder in my computer.
2. Install Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools.
3. Run the setup script that is in the root folder (`python setup.py install`).

Errors:

`File "c:\users\sito\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\dream-0.0.1-py3.7.egg\dream\simulation\applications\DemandPlanning\AllocManagement_Hybrid.py", line 38 print G.priorityList ^ SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(G.priorityList)?

File "c:\users\sito\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\dream-0.0.1-py3.7.egg\dream\simulation\applications\DemandPlanning\AllocationForecast_IP.py", line 150 print 'lp results', item['sp'], allQty, LpStatus[prob.status], sum(MA_var[ma].varValue* G.BatchSize[ma][week] for ma in MAlist) ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

File "c:\users\sito\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\dream-0.0.1-py3.7.egg\dream\simulation\applications\DemandPlanning\AllocationRoutine_ForecastGA.py", line 51 print 'item', item['orderID'] ^ SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print('item', item['orderID'])?

File "c:\users\sito\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\dream-0.0.1-py3.7.egg\dream\simulation\applications\DemandPlanning\Allocation_ACO.py", line 138 print 'Termination Criterion Reached' ... error: Setup script exited with error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https:⁄/visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/`

Comment: "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/" -- do you have Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools 14 installed? Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017  might do.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have had  c++ build tools 14 installed. And now the errors are "installed_mysql.c(42): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Comment: hmm, its different issue already, you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866147/mysql-python-install-error-cannot-open-include-file-config-win-h) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972259/cannot-open-include-file-config-win-h-no-such-file-or-directory-while-inst). perhaps i should get a python myself to see this..

Comment: Thanks@BagusTesa. I find errors like print xxxx. I guess the lib is based on Python 2.x. I will try.

Comment: It works with Python 2.7. Just to install c++9.                                                        error: Setup script exited with error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required. Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27. Thanks @BagusTesa

Comment: wah, never thought that the python version mismatched. my bad. i never thought that was the reason. glad you solved it already.

Comment: I installed C++ 9.0 compiler. Then I got                                                           Running MySQL-python-1.2.5\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\stglj\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-jpq7ak\MySQL-python-1.2.5\egg-dist-tmp-xng2z0
_mysql.c
_mysql.c(42) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'C:\\Users\\stglj\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Comment: I guess the connector was not installed properly, which causes "config-win.h" missing. I have mysql 5.5 on my computer.  Not sure how to fix it. I am new to  Python ecology, SimPy and ManPy. I have been working with Java for a long time. The shift seems harder than I expected. Thanks.