# how to fix mysqlclient error , it cant be downloaded , (wndows os)

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

a error code appear:

```
 ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\python\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MOHAME~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jdsmmbmj\\mysql-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-oxb6oxgo\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -Ic:\python\include -Ic:\python\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
    _mysql.c
    _mysql.c(42): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'c:\python\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MOHAME~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jdsmmbmj\\mysql-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-oxb6oxgo\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\MOHAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jdsmmbmj\mysql-python\


pip install mysqlclient
pip install pymysql
pip install mysqlclient==1.3.9
pip install --only-binary :all: mysqlclient
pip install mysql-python
```

Comment: You're missing [libmysqlclient](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/)

Comment: check answer there, prefer direct download method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866147/mysql-python-install-error-cannot-open-include-file-config-win-h