# pip install mysql-python fails with missing config-win.h

Tags: python, django, mysql-python

The python command is `pip install mysql-python`

The full error is `_mysql.c(42): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory`

Can someone please tell me how to fix this error?

What exactly is mysql-python and how is it different from regular mysql?

Another stack overflow post suggested installing it with a setup executable, where can I find this?

I installed something called mysql python connector from here:
https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-c/
It installed into `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1`

However, I cannot find `mysqld` executable anywhere in this folder

Does this install mysql or do I actually need to install it from the Oracle website?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql-python install error: Cannot open include file 'config-win.h'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866147/mysql-python-install-error-cannot-open-include-file-config-win-h)

Comment: No, unfortunately, because all the answers just tell to install `mysqlclient` and I tried doing this, but its not the same thing as mysql-python. I cannot find this `mysqld` executable anywhere

Comment: Mysqlclient is a fork of mysql-python, which supports python3, while the original version does not. This is why installing mysqlclient is the accepted answer there. Mysqld is the mysql server executable.

Comment: Ok, but how do I actually start mysql? Do I need to download the 400 mb installer from Oracle website?

Comment: You are mixing lots of questions here. First, you are asking how to install a python connector for mysql, now you are asking a completely different question. Pls make up your mind what you would like to know and stick to that.

Comment: you can install the MySQL connector with `pip install mysql-connector-python` and the python MySQL client using `pip install PyMySQL`

Comment: my question, as its stated above, Do I need to download the 400 mb mysql installer from Oracle website in order to use mysqlclient?

Answer (score 0):

This required the full MySql server installation from Oracle

Answer (score 0):

`mysql-python` is a module built for python-2 for interfacing with the mysql server so this does not include the mysql server and there is a fork of the same module called `mysqlclient` for python-3.

The reason for your error is you haven't installed Visual Studio 2019 to compile the c/c++ code in the python package. If you don't want to install Visual Studio 2019 check out these Python Wheel (.whl) files according to your python version

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python (Python 2)
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient  (Python 3)