# Can't Install mysql- for Python / Django (Windows)

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to download through `pip` the MySql-python connector as following, however im getting an  `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).`

```
C:\Users\yschellekens.INTRANET\Desktop\Django project\general>pip install MySQL-
python
You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 7.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' comm
and.
Collecting MySQL-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Building wheels for collected packages: MySQL-python
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for MySQL-python
  Complete output from command C:\Python33\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__fi
le__='c:\\users\\yschel~1.int\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-wc92bo\\MySQL-pyt
hon\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file_
_, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d c:\users\yschel~1.int\appdata\local\temp\tmpc71e54pi
p-wheel-:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.3
  copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.3
  creating build\lib.win32-3.3\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.3\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.3\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.3\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.3\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.3\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.3\MySQLdb
  creating build\lib.win32-3.3\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.3\MySQLdb\constants

  copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.3\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.3\MySQLdb\constan
ts
  copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.3\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.3\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win32-3.3\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.3\MySQLdb\constants
  running build_ext
  building '_mysql' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for MySQL-python
Failed to build MySQL-python
Installing collected packages: MySQL-python
  Running setup.py install for MySQL-python
    Complete output from command C:\Python33\python.exe -c "import setuptools, t
okenize;__file__='c:\\users\\yschel~1.int\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-wc92b
o\\MySQL-python\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__
).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\ys
chel~1.int\appdata\local\temp\pip-ckxp_c-record\install-record.txt --single-vers
ion-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).


    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Python33\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\us
ers\\yschel~1.int\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-wc92bo\\MySQL-python\\setup.p
y';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n',
 '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\yschel~1.int\appdata\local
\temp\pip-ckxp_c-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed -
-compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\yschel~1.int\appdata\local\temp\p
ip-build-wc92bo\MySQL-python
```

I found this wonderful question, which was very helpful:
[Install mysql-python (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440230/install-mysql-python-windows)

But im still running into issues, i know that i can download Visual Studio 2010 but i saw people who mention that its not necessary, and i prefer not to download it.

Here are my **PYTHONPATH** + **PATH**

PATH:

```
C:\Tools\OpenVPN\bin;C:\Python33\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\jre\bin\server;C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages;C:\Python33\Lib;C:\Python33\DLLs;C:\Python33\Lib\lib-tk;C:\Python33\Scripts;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin
```

PYTHONPATH

```
C:\Python33;C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages;C:\Python33\Lib;C:\Python33\DLLs;C:\Python33\Lib\lib-tk;C:\Python33\Scripts
```

Did i miss anything?

Any help in that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to have `Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0` compiler (and as far as I remember version 10.0 doesn't necessarily mean `Visual Studio 2010`) installed on your system and `vcvarsall.bat` accessible from `PATH` environment variable.

However, it is usual for Windows to have enormous amount of blocking issues connected with compiling python extensions via pip (or it's just me?), so my usual workaround of the error you get is to google some Windows binary installers ([mysql-python for 2.7 for instance](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python)) or `.whl` files. Both have python extensions compiled for a particular Python and architecture thus eliminating the need in having C or C++ compiler installed.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it seems like i have problems loading Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 compiler, ill try to fix it this week and update you :)

Comment: thanks, I've installed Visual C++, now i have a new problem using pip (as you implied) now will need to solve that :)