# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb' Amazon MySQL RDS SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

I am having issues with connecting Amazon AWS MySQL with SQLAlchemy. According to the instruction, I have connected.

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://<user>:<password>@<host>/<dbname>
```

But there is an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ec2-user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 514, in __get__
    return type.query_class(mapper, session=self.sa.session())
  File "/home/ec2-user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 74, in __call__
    return self.registry()
  File "/home/ec2-user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 1001, in __call__
    return self.registry.setdefault(key, self.createfunc())
  File "/home/ec2-user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2950, in __call__
    return self.class_(**local_kw)
  File "/home/ec2-user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 143, in __init__
    bind = options.pop('bind', None) or db.engine
  File "/home/ec2-user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 877, in engine
    return self.get_engine()
  File "/home/ec2-user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 896, in get_engine
    return connector.get_engine()
  File "/home/ec2-user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 559, in get_engine
    self._engine = rv = sqlalchemy.create_engine(info, **options)
  File "/home/ec2-user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 424, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 81, in create
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "/home/ec2-user/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py", line 102, in dbapi
    return __import__('MySQLdb')
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

I am using Python3.7 version. Even according to the stackoverflow, I have installed pymysql, but still facing the problem.

Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 5):

If you use the PyMySQL client to connect to MySQL, your SQLAlchemy connection string needs to start with

```
 mysql+pymysql://
```

instead of `mysql://`.

If you connect with `mysql://` then you will need to install the MySQLdb library as shown in the Traceback.

Comment: Solves the problem, but would someone add some explanation of what's happening? (I would ask a question; but I'm not sure yet what the question would be.)

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1**
If you want to use MySQLDB you need to use one of the following commands. Which one depends on what OS and software you have and use.

`easy_install mysql-python` (mix os)

`pip install mysql-python` (mix os/ python 2)

`pip install mysqlclient` (mix os/ python 3)

`apt-get install python-mysqldb` (Linux Ubuntu, ...)

`cd /usr/ports/databases/py-MySQLdb && make install clean` (FreeBSD)

`yum install MySQL-python` (Linux Fedora, CentOS ...)

For Windows, see this answer: [Install mysql-python (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21440230/4646678)

**Step 2:**

1. Create Engine

`engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://...', pool_recycle=3600)`

use the `create_engine.pool_recycle` option which ensures that a connection will be discarded and replaced with a new one if it has been present in the pool for a fixed number of seconds:

2. Create Connection object

`conn = engine.connect()`

3. Execute SQL queries

`conn.execute("SELECT * From table;")`

Comment: Above issues has been solved:    import pymysql                                                                 pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()                  Thank you all for suggestion. Nothing to change in other

Comment: this fails for me with `python-mysqldb has no installation candidate`

Answer (score 2):

Above issues has been solved with the following:

```
import pymysql

pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

Nothing to change anywhere.