# Facing problem in installing mysqlclient in python

Tags: django, visual-studio, build-tools, django-mysql, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I am a beginner in python. I am doing my college project in django-python. I want to use MySQL (phpMyAdmin). I am facing problem in installing mysqlclient.
The error is given below...

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,3,12,'final',0) -D__version__=1.3.12 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include" -Ic:\users\bhuvan_02\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include -Ic:\users\bhuvan_02\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\cppwinrt" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release_mysql.obj /Zl**

_mysql.c
   _mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Any type of help is appreciated...

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440230/install-mysql-python-windows

Answer (score 0):

Install older version, latest version 1.3.13 is having problems.
`pip install mysqlclient==1.3.12`