# import django ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django' after install python 2

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-2.x, django-1.11

I have 3 django projects (version 1.11.15), and all errors after I accidentally install Python 2 (I installed the react native), before I used python 3.6.5 via Anaconda.

Some of my project files appear error symbols. And when I try to run "manage.py runserver", it can't run, and an error appears. I uninstalled Python 2, and reinstalled my Anaconda (Python 3.6.5), but it didn't work.

In my opinion there is a problem in the path, but I don't know what that is. I've been looking for a solution, but nothing works. Anyone has a solution? ... thanks

[image: error]

[image]

my python version

[image: python version]

this is my python path, I don't know what to add here, I just followed a few tutorials that I found
[image]
[image]

this is my path
[image: my path]

This is my requirement.txt

[image: requiremen.txt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfeeP.png)

i found it,
it's " python manage.py runserver " not " manage.py runserver "

Comment: it's work. I have been reinstall my Anaconda. and set Python.exe as  default program for my .py file

Answer (score 1):

I have ran into this problem and I found the easiest solution was to write out requirements.txt and remove any unwanted libraries. Then delete the virtualenv and recreate a new with the new requirements.

Comment: Do you get the same error and can you post your requirements.txt?

Comment: now the error is changed to "import MySQLdb as Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb' "

Comment: and you can see on my picture [pip list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzxzU.png) i have installed mysqlclient

Comment: For the Mysqldb error did you install the mysql connector?

Comment: take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440230/install-mysql-python-windows the choosen answer sounds like it would help you here