# settings causing mysql to throw error

Tags: mysql, django

I have installed mysql in my virtual environment using this command and it has installed successfully..

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
sudo pip install MySQL-python
```

Now in my settings.py I have done this..

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db_hotelnepal'),
}
}
```

But when I run server it throws error saying ""Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb""...

Whats the prob and how can I fix ?

Comment: check `pip freeze` and make sure `MySQL-python==1.2.5` is there or not ?

Comment: Please read the second answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189813/setting-django-up-to-use-mysql/

Comment: Now it throws the error saying ""django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")""

Answer (score 0):

MySQL-python is not compatible with python 3, and it gives this error. You didn't mention the python version you are using, but I have only seen this when using python 3 and MySQL, so I will make that assumption. I use MySQL-for-Python-3 which can be found here: [MySQL-for-Python-3](https://github.com/davispuh/MySQL-for-Python-3). It is compatible with python 2.7-3.3, haven't had a project with MySQL and python 3.4 to try it yet.

I install by running pip install https://github.com/davispuh/MySQL-for-Python-3/archive/1.0.tar.gz

Comment: Nope the version of python is 2.7