# Using scripts python in website, is django what I want?

Tags: python, django, web

I've been reading some info about django and I saw some youtube videos about websites made with django but I don't really understand what it really is, so I have a question.
If for example I had an script named script.py that given an url, let's say: http://www.stackoverflow.com printed in console http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions , would i use django to make this script runnable from the website and the "print" would be in the website itself?
I know I would have to change the code to insted of print create an html tag like `<p>http://www.stackoverflow.com/</p>` or something like this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends!

If you're just doing simple forms and scripts, you could check out the [Python CGI](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html) modules. This would suffice for your example above.

If you want to do more complex stuff, I highly recommend using a microframework such as [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). This will make scripting very easy, and there are a number of extensions you can use to streamline your code further.

Comment: so django is not useful for what I want to do? I'd also make connections to some mysql database

Comment: no actually i didn't said `django is not userful`. I said `Django is very powerful` ....

Comment: @lluk12 see this link for setting up mysql http://stackoverflow.com/a/19189930/3762142

Comment: Django is a templating web language that is included with Flask. You can use mysql commands within your python code, which can then output to a Django template.
Django's learning curve is very nice—If you find it useful, I think you will find you will pick it up rather quickly.