# Unable to connect mysql via django

Tags: mysql, django, django-settings

I know this is an old question on lots of forums with answers suggesting to do flush privileges and reset passwords but in my case no answer has worked.

Here's the scenario:

I am able to connect to mysql via following command

```
mysql -u root -p -hlocalhost
```

I am also able to connect via python using following script

```
import MySQLdb
Con = MySQLdb.Connect(host="127.0.0.1", port=3306, user="root", passwd="mypass", db="mydb")
Cursor = Con.cursor()
sql = "SELECT * FROM test"
Cursor.execute(sql) #### gives 1L
```

But I am unable to connect via Django. Django settings.py contains

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWD': 'mypass',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Following is the main error

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")

Please suggest.

Comment: and you seriously followed all of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19189930/1816093) steps ?

Comment: Try ``127.0.0.1`` not localhost.

Comment: @Drew yes. :-( The only doubt I have is if both /usr/bin/mysqld_safe and /usr/sbin/mysqld supposed to run at the same time? while recovering root password, I had tried mysqld_safe. After that I have shutdown/restarted mysql many times.

Comment: @GlynJackson doesn't work

Comment: Your error says password 'NO' yet you specified a password in your OP.

Comment: I guess you didn't follow that first step I mentioned 32 minutes ago !

Comment: @Drew while configuring, I had copied from one of the answers provided by AlphaCentauri on the link you provided where the spelling was wrong. It went unnoticed to my eyes and then no review of the steps in any link helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key for the password value in the db settings should be "PASSWORD", not "PASSWD".

Comment: I noticed that. There are references to other answers otherwise. Definitely try that ... that could easily be throwing the NO PASSWORD

Comment: beat me too it :) Error states he is not sending a password.