# Python Connector for Django 1.9 and Python 3.5?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm working with the latest version of Python and Django as of the date of this question and I cannot find a connector that will work for MySQL which supports Python 3.5.  Does anybody have a solution to this problem?  I'm running on a Windows platform.

When I try to download the mysqlclient from here [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient), I'm running Python 3.5.1 32 on Windows 8.1.  I download the wheel, I attempt to install the wheel file using pip, I get the error that

> mysqlclient-1.3.7-cp27-none-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this
>   platform.

Apparently this wheel is supposed to work on Python 3.5.

To make sure I'm not having a problem elsewhere, since I'm new to this whl format, I downloaded another package (BeautifulSoup4) and confirmed the installation of that wheel file is working, so it appears to be a problem with my operating system and the wheel file for mysqlclient.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As [cgohlke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/453463/cgohlke) said, **mysqlclient can not currently be compiled on Python 3.5 for Windows because the MySQL Connector/C is not yet compatible with the Visual Studio 2015 compiler required by Python 3.5.**

Follow the related GitHub issue : [mysqlclient-python - Not working with python 3.5](http://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/issues/54) to be aware when this bug will be fixed.

When this issue will be fixed, [mysqlclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient) should work.

**Temporary solution with unofficial Windows binaries : [mysqlclient-1.3.7](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient)**

From [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/databases/#id9) 1.9 documentation :

> Django supports MySQL 5.5 and higher.
>
> Django requires mysqlclient 1.3.3 or later. Note that Python 3.2 is not supported. Except for the Python 3.3+ support, mysqlclient should mostly behave the same as MySQLDB.

From [mysqlclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient) 1.3.7 package index :

> mysqlclient is a fork of MySQL-python. It adds Python 3.3~ support and merges some pull requests.
>
> MySQL-4.1 through 5.5 and Python-2.7, 3.3-3.5 are currently supported. PyPy is supported.

Comment: thanks for whatever reason anytime I try to install that wheel it says it's not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: add error message, and your windows version please. I bet your are on Windows 10 :D

Comment: damn, okay thanks for the help guys, I spent an hour or so already on this and don't care to spend more time.  I suppose I should downgrade to Python 3.4 :(

Comment: Louis, if you could update this answer to the fact that Python 3.5 is not yet supported at the time of this answer I can accept the answer.  Thank you.

Comment: yeah, I updated the answer. Thank you @cgohlke for your comment. Merry Xmas

Comment: mysqlclient wheels for Python 3.5 are now available at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient