# OperationalError: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to run a server in python/django and I'm getting the following error:

> django.db.uils.OperationslError: (200, "Can't connect to local MySQL
>   server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)").

I have `MySQL-python` installed (1.2.5 version) and mysql installed (0.0.1), both via pip, so I'm not sure why I can't connect to the MySQL server. Does anyone know why? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting Django up to use MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189813/setting-django-up-to-use-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

You can't install mysql through pip; it's a database, not a Python library (and it's currently in version 5.7). You need to install the binary package for your operating system.

Comment: What about if I install with through brew? It says it's installed there, and the version is mysql 5.7.15. should that work?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. If you're still having problems, post your DATABASES settings.

Comment: Okay, I'm still getting that error message, so here's my DATABASES settings:

DATABASES = {

    "default": {

        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",

        "NAME": os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT,'../..','dev.db'),

        "HOST": "localhost",

        "PORT": "5171",

        "USER": "root",

        "PASSWORD": "",

        }

}

Comment: And you're still getting the error message to do with the socket? Something odd happening then because your setting clearly specifies a port, not a socket. Are you sure that is the right settings file? Is that setting being overridden further down the file?

Comment: Also note that your NAME setting makes no sense, you should use a database name there not a file path, but that didn't cause your error (although it will cause a different error once you've got this one fixed).