# not working running python manage.py rusnerver

Tags: python, django, manage.py, django-manage.py

when running that command `python manage.py runserver` I get this error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

I try to `pip install mysqlclient` and get this

```
Command "C:\Users\xavi6\PycharmProjects\LES\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\xavi6\\App
Data\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8q8y5ra6\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\
n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\xavi6\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-zvgp3gov\inst
all-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\xavi6\PycharmProjects\LES\venv\include\site\py
thon3.7\mysqlclient" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\xavi6\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8q8y5ra6\mysqlclient\
```

I'm using pycharm and I think I try everything. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Is this a new project? which Django version? What is your database configuration on the `settings.py` on your app

Comment: I change that to mysql, is the only change i do, yes its the last version of django and is a new project.

`DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'django_test',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
}`

Comment: i tried `pip install --upgrade setuptools` too

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` to install python dependencies and then `pip install mysqlclient`. More [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189813/setting-django-up-to-use-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

have you installed pip install **mysqlclient**

Then edit init.py

```
import pymysql

pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

and then let me know it worked or not.Happy coding

Comment: i tried and i got an error, i do `pip install mysqlclient` and got that error

`Command "C:\Users\xavi6\PycharmProjects\LES\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\xavi6\\App
Data\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_k6zdj2w\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\
n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record 
`

Comment: ` C:\Users\xavi6\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-vie_6885\inst
all-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\xavi6\PycharmProjects\LES\venv\include\site\py
thon3.7\mysqlclient" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\xavi6\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_k6zdj2w\mysqlclient\ 
`

Comment: and in init.py says that theres no ` no module named pymysql `